# How do I override a dependency's dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm

Not sure this is possible, but I need to override the version of a dependency's dependency. Specifically, I have this in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "connect": "*"
}
```

`connect` then has a dependency on `"formidable": "1.0.11"`. I need `connect` to use version `1.0.13` of `formidable`.

Is it possible to override `connect`'s dependency without cloning that project?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have a similar problem.

Comment: npm shrinkwrap works for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)

Answer (score 1):

You can set "formidable": "1.0.13" at your package.json and if other package (in this case connect) which depends on formidable has appropriate condition to formidable version they will share single formidable package. In case of latest connect it doesn't work because it has "formidable": "1.0.11" at package.json and if you set "1.0.13" at your package.json you will get two formidable installed ("1.0.13" as your direct dependency and "1.0.11" as connect dependency). AFAIK, it's impossible to override dependency in this case.