# How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to use the `grunt-contrib-jasmine` NPM package. It has various dependencies. Part of the dependency graph looks like this:

```
─┬ grunt-contrib-jasmine@0.4.1
 │ ├─┬ grunt-lib-phantomjs@0.2.0
 │ │ ├─┬ phantomjs@1.8.2-2
```

Unfortunately, there's a bug in this version `phantomjs` which prevents it from installing correctly on Mac OS X. This is fixed in the latest version.

**How can I get `grunt-lib-phantomjs` to use a newer version of `phantomjs`?**

Some additional context:

- `grunt-contrib-jasmine` explicitly requires version `"~0.2.0"` of `grunt-lib-phantomjs`, which explicitly requires version `"~1.8.1"` of `phantomjs`.
- Adding `phantomjs` to my package's dependencies first has no effect; both versions are installed and `grunt-contrib-jasmine` still uses the older versions (see: [When installing a package with NPM, can you tell it to use a different version of one of its dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233133/when-installing-a-package-with-npm-can-you-tell-it-to-use-a-different-version-o)).

Comment: Just `git clone` or fork required module. You can also remove nested `phantomjs` manually.

Comment: [`grunt-contrib-jasmine`](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-jasmine) is on 0.5.1, which uses `grunt-lib-phantomjs@0.3.1`, which uses `phantomjs@1.9.1-0` :)

Comment: npm plans to release [overrides](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/129) in the future

Comment: `overrides` are now a built-in feature. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70396201/120955) below.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

As of npm [v8.3](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.3.0) (released with [Node.js 16](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases)), the correct way to deal with this is via the `overrides` section of your `package.json` file.

> If you need to make specific changes to dependencies of your
> dependencies, for example replacing the version of a dependency with a
> known security issue, replacing an existing dependency with a fork, or
> making sure that the same version of a package is used everywhere,
> then you may add an override.
>
> Overrides provide a way to replace a package in your dependency tree
> with another version, or another package entirely. These changes can
> be scoped as specific or as vague as desired.
>
> To make sure the package foo is always installed as version 1.0.0 no
> matter what version your dependencies rely on:
>
> ```
> {
>   "overrides": {
>     "foo": "1.0.0"
>   }
> }
> ```

There are a variety of other, more nuanced configurations allowing you to only override a package when it's a dependency of a particular package hierarchy. For more details, check out https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Comment: @georgebrock please consider marking this as the correct answer -- the ecosystem has changed since you asked the question and this is a high ranking Google result

Comment: Consider adding `"engines": { "npm": ">=8.3.0" }` to your package.json to indicate that a new npm version is required

Comment: This tripped me up: if you use a monorepo with workspaces, you need to define overrides in the root package, not in the nested projects with the actual dependencies.

Comment: I added this to package.json but not work with yarn install. I use yarn. But I added it that maybe anyone else possibly can use npm. I hope this is also works with npm.

Comment: Great advice from @leumasme! We expanded it with `engine-strict=true` inside `.npmrc` to not only get a warning, since the dependency that needs to be overriding breaks a lot for us.

Comment: Note that there are issues with the implementation of the overrides property and it's reported to only work with the first `npm install` command: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5443

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I wish that `npm audit force` also made fixes by using overrides - right now it just updates the package-lock.json, which suffers from all the same problems brought up in the comments to Viraj Singh's answer.

Answer (score 340):

**As of npm cli [v8.3.0](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.3.0) (2021-12-09) this can be solved using the [`overrides` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) of package.json**. *As described in [StriplingWarrior's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70396201/1139105)*

For example, the project has `typescript` version `4.6.2` as *direct* development dependency and `awesome-typescript-loader` that uses old version `2.7` of `typescript`. Here is how you can tell `npm` to use version `4.6.2` of `typescript` for `awesome-typescript-loader`:

```json
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": ...
  "dependencies": ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "~4.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    ...
  },
  "overrides": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": {
      "typescript": "$typescript"
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't use `typescript` as *direct* development dependency, then you have to write `4.6.2` instead of `$typescript` in `overrides` section:

```json
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": ...
  "dependencies": ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    ...
  },
  "overrides": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": {
      "typescript": "~4.6.2"
    }
  }
}
```

For using the latest version of dependency:

```json
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": ...
  "dependencies": ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    ...
  },
  "overrides": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": {
      "typescript": "latest"
    }
  }
}
```

Same `overrides` can be used for both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

---

If you're using npm version >5 but <8.3.0: edit your `package-lock.json`: remove the library from `"requires"` section and add it under "dependencies".

For example, you want `deglob` package to use `glob` package version `3.2.11` instead of its current one. You open `package-lock.json` and see:

```json
"deglob": {
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/deglob/-/deglob-2.1.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-TUSr4W7zLHebSXK9FBqAMlApoUo=",
  "requires": {
    "find-root": "1.1.0",
    "glob": "7.1.2",
    "ignore": "3.3.5",
    "pkg-config": "1.1.1",
    "run-parallel": "1.1.6",
    "uniq": "1.0.1"
  }
},
```

Remove `"glob": "7.1.2",` from `"requires"`, add `"dependencies"` with proper version:

```json
"deglob": {
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/deglob/-/deglob-2.1.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-TUSr4W7zLHebSXK9FBqAMlApoUo=",
  "requires": {
    "find-root": "1.1.0",
    "ignore": "3.3.5",
    "pkg-config": "1.1.1",
    "run-parallel": "1.1.6",
    "uniq": "1.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "glob": {
      "version": "3.2.11"
    }
  }
},
```

Now remove your `node_modules` folder, run `npm ci` (or `npm install` for old version of node/npm) and it will add missing parts to the `"dependencies"` section.

---

Comment: This is nice, as long as `npm install` runs one time. In my case the edits are necessary as the nested dep is causing a fail.

Comment: this will be removed anytime you run `npm i` instead of editing your package-lock.json and adding the child dependency to "dependencies" there, add the child dependency to your package.json "dependencies" section

Comment: Better yet, add it to your `devDependencies`, since you aren't really using that module on your code.

Comment: I've created a library that does exactly that for you automatically: https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions

Comment: @trickpatty I tried to add the new version (in my case cssnano/@next) to devDependencies, but my the package I want to change the dependency for (in my case css-loader), still uses cssnano/@latest. Could you please elaborate on how to force it to use another /@next instead of /@latest? Thank you.

Comment: @Magnus Does overriding dependencies via `package-lock.json` work in your case?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm still getting the unwanted version of the child dependency.

Comment: @FeeFiFoFum please provide information about your Node version (it works for me on Node 8.4.0) and check if the dependency is duplicated somewhere (e.g. if package A requires version 1 of package B, and package C requires version 1 of package B, and you want to override version of B, you must override it for both A and C).

Comment: What is the workaround for `npm install` undoing this?

Comment: @2rs2ts The last paragraph says that `npm install` should add missing dependencies, not ignore all your changes. Please make sure this works: remove `package-lock.json`, run `npm install`, edit `package-lock.json` the way it's described in the answer, then delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` once again. Will it work for you?

Comment: It works but then if I run `npm install` again then all the changes to `package-lock.json` get reverted and I get the bad version of the dep back.

Comment: I run `npm ci` and this does not touch the `package-lock.json`

Comment: how do i specify a git repo instead of version?

Comment: @DanielLizik E.g.,

"dependencies": {
        "graphql-relay": {
          "version": "0.6.0",
          "resolved": "git@github.com:LMBernardo/graphql-relay-js.git#6dbd6f3cb0fa901620a85c16c8522d240f4315b4"
        }
}

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for `peerDependencies` :'(

Comment: Note that the option in **pnpm** is `pnpm.overrides` and `overrides` won't take effect

Answer (score 287):

You can use [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) functionality, in order to override any dependency or sub-dependency.

I've just done this in a `grunt` project of ours. We needed a newer version of connect, since `2.7.3`. was causing trouble for us. So I created a file named `npm-shrinkwrap.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-connect": {
      "version": "0.3.0",
      "from": "grunt-contrib-connect@0.3.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "connect": {
          "version": "2.8.1",
          "from": "connect@~2.7.3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`npm` should automatically pick it up while doing the install for the project.

(See: https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/)

Comment: Nice and simple! But you don't really need `from`. Why do you add it?

Comment: When I do this, only the `grunt-contrib-connect` dependency and its children are installed. All my other dependencies in package.json are not installed.

Comment: I had the same issue as @iDVB. I ended up editing the `node_modules` directory so that the full shrinkwrap dependency dump was exactly what I wanted, not just overrides. But still a kind of painful solution.

Comment: @Domi this file is created by running npm shrinkwrap, the entries are not added by hand

Comment: why at one line it says `grunt-contrib-connect@0.3.0` and then on another line only `connect` --> `connect@~2.7.3`

Comment: Thank you!  `npm shrinkwrap` wouldn't run because of "unmet peer dependencies" until I manually created a npm-shrinkwrap.json file per your template here and overrode "peerDependencies".  Once I did that I could remove the .json file and then `npm shrinkwrap` ran fine. Yay!

Comment: Agreed, its a pain to generate a full shrinkwrap file and edit only the sub or sub-sub dependencies with `npm 2.x (node4)` but with `npm 3.x (node5)` we can be minimalistic and only create a shrinkwrap file to address exactly what needs to be overridden. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7108

Comment: Unfortunately, as is mentioned in that bug, with npm4, the minimalistic approach no longer works. (When deleting `node_modules`, running an install with a minimal shrinkwrap seems to leave `devDependencies` intact though ignoring `dependencies`, but running another install removes the non-explicit items, so for now it is important to run `npm shrinkwrap` to get a full file, modify the portion in question, and then run `npm install` again)

Comment: use `npm shrinkwrap` to generate it, but be aware that this will make **npm-shrinkwrap.json** take precedence over any other existing or future **package-lock.json** files

Comment: npm 6.4 will just overwrite the shrinkwrap file and use the outdated dependencies

Comment: If you already have a package-lock.json (and you almost definitely do) then the shrinkwrap file you create will be incorporated into your package-lock.json the next time you `install` because you cannot have both.

Comment: This way you're basically ditching your `package-lock.json`. That is, your packages are going to be updated in accordance with the `package.json` file. And this is a hack, your override will vanish the next time `npm` has to [change something](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/1513e1fdb288cc9f683d7e672a748a57#npm-shrinkwrapjson-solution).

Comment: using npm 6.13.1. I have a similar scenario. My project calls "A" that depends on "B" that depends on "C, 1.0.0" and I want to force B to use "C, 2.0.0". What do I have to do?

Answer (score 104):

The only solution that worked for me (node 12.x, npm 6.x) was using [npm-force-resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions) developed by [@Rogerio Chaves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996404/rogerio-chaves).

First, install it by:

```bash
npm install npm-force-resolutions --save-dev
```

You can add `--ignore-scripts` if some broken transitive dependency scripts are blocking you from installing anything.

Then in `package.json` define what dependency should be overridden (you must set **exact version number**):

```json
"resolutions": {
  "your-dependency-name": "1.23.4"
}
```

and in `"scripts"` section add new preinstall entry:

```json
"preinstall": "npm-force-resolutions",
```

Now, `npm install` will apply changes and force `your-dependency-name` to be at version `1.23.4` for all dependencies.

Comment: hint: use `--save-dev` flag for `npm install`

Comment: this would not work if one wants to upgrade corresponding dependency only for one particular  3rd party dependency

Comment: Note: this works only when you have package-lock.json enabled, which some devs might not have due to its inherent problems.

Comment: Is there any built-in solution in latest versions of NPM as per year 2021? I would not like to depend on a third party library for this kind of things - manipulating dependency tree.

Comment: @DaniP. npm is poor's man dependency manager, so I doubt it

Comment: For me the preinstall command broke in Circle CI, so i used this one instead:

```"preinstall": "npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts && npx npm-force-resolutions"```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67446313/6627882

Comment: @keemor worth mentioning that's completely different library with similar name and purpose

Answer (score 67):

For those using yarn.

I tried using npm shrinkwrap until I discovered the yarn cli ignored my npm-shrinkwrap.json file.

Yarn has https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/ for this. Neat.

Check out this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082766/3051080

Answer (score 10):

### Nested replacement with an entirely different package

Most of the strategies outlined in the other answers here work well if you are just interested in overriding the package's version number, but in our case, we needed to find a way to override a nested npm sub-dependency with a **different package** altogether. For details on why you would ever want to do this, please refer to the following question:

[How to override a nested npm sub-dependency with a different package altogether (not just different package version number)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69548370/how-to-override-a-nested-npm-sub-dependency-with-a-different-package-altogether/69591894)

### Specify the tarball directly

For nested replacement of a package with an entirely different package using the `npm-force-resolutions` strategy that others have mentioned, you just need to provide a link to the tarball where you would normally specify the overriding version number.

As an example, for the case of replacing the vulnerable package, `ansi-html`, with the fixed fork of this package, `ansi-html-community`, your resolutions section of `package.json` should look like this:

```json
"resolutions": {
    "ansi-html": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-html-community/-/ansi-html-community-0.0.8.tgz"
}
```

To find the link to the tarball, use the following command, modifying your registry as necessary:

```
npm view ansi-html-community dist.tarball --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Also, note that for `npm-force-resolutions` to work when you run `npm install`, you will need a `preinstall` entry under the `scripts` section of `package.json`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really useful. I thought replacing a package would have been possible by overriding using a reference e.g. `"bar": "$foo"` as documented in the last example [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) but I couldn't get it to work. But your solution did the trick and I would give an extra point for the details.

Comment: npm uses `"overrides"` instead of `"resolutions"`

Answer (score 10):

Based on the rest of the answers, I provide the same solution, but I display the package.json, as I struggled a little bit on where to place the override and how.

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "snapshot",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build-dev": "ng build --configuration development",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~14.2.9"
  ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.8",
  ....
  },
  "overrides": {
    "loader-utils@>2.0.0 <3": "2.0.4",
    "loader-utils@>3.0.0 <4": "3.2.1"
  }
}
```

For November 2022 "loader-utils" security vulnerability, it was requested to

- use the version 2.0.4, if you are in the 2.X
- use the version 3.2.1, if you are in the 3.X

And to verify

- add the package.json the override tag
- delete the package-lock.json
- run "npm install"
- run "npm audit"

Comment: Wouldn't this `loader-utils@>3.0.0 <4` override a future 3.3 to 3.2.1?

Comment: yes, for the time being 3.2.1 is the only safe one though. This was an example, it does not have to cover all the potential cases.

Answer (score 3):

@user11153 's answer worked for me locally, but when trying to do a clean install (aka deleting `node_modules`), I would get:

```
npm-force-resolutions: command not found
```

I had to update the `preinstall` script to be:

```
"preinstall": "npm i npm-force-resolutions && npm-force-resolutions"
```

Which ensures that `npm-force-resolutions` package is installed before attempting to run it.

That being said, if you're able to use yarn instead, I would do that and then use [@Gus 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241894/6424295).

Comment: I used ```"preinstall": "npx force-resolutions"``` as suggested here https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions/issues/10#issuecomment-885458937

Comment: There's also a more speedier route via a bit of `bash`ery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68095189/132735

Comment: There is no answer by "Gus".
Could you instead explicitly link to the answer you refer to when writing
*and then use @Gus 's answer*?

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue where one of the nested dependency had an npm audit vulnerability, but I still wanted to maintain the parent dependency version. the npm shrinkwrap solution didn't work for me, so what I did to override the nested dependency version:

1. Remove the nested dependency under the 'requires' section in package-lock.json
2. Add the updated dependency under DevDependencies in package.json, so that modules that require it will still be able to access it.
3. npm i

Comment: using npm 6 this does NOT work.   npm i overwrites any change to the package lock file

Answer (score 2):

I was about to go down the `npm-force-resolutions` route but it seems that simply including the dependency in my own `package.json` fixed the problem for me.

I believe this worked in my case because the original dependency allows for patch versions of the dependency in question that I wanted to update. Thus by manually including a newer version it still fulfilled the dependency of the original dependency and will use the one I've manually added.

## Example

### Problem

I need to update `plyr` to version `3.6.9` from `3.6.8`

### Mine

`package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-plyr": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

### React Plyr

`package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "plyr": "^3.6.8"
  }
}
```

> Notice for the `plyr` dependency it starts with `^` this means it can accept any minor patches. You can learn more about that here:
>
> https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning#using-semantic-versioning-to-specify-update-types-your-package-can-accept

### Updating Mine

This updates the `plyr` dependency from my `package.json`.

`package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "plyr": "^3.6.9",
    "react-plyr": "^3.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the override technique to work for me, at least not to prevent the error. <sup>1</sup>

I also couldn't use `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`  as in `npm install --force`. I can run `npm install --force` locally but I don't know how to run that command on the server (I happen to use Google AppEngine, deployed using `gcloud.cmd app deploy`)

I was able to fix my issue with two steps:

1. **manually modify my package-lock.json** to remove the offending peer dependency:

   - the problem was the ["Could not resolve dependency...  Fix the upstream dependency conflict" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)
   - modifying package-lock.json directly to fix dependency conflicts is also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77009444/1175496)  (I admit this solution is hacky)
2. **call `npm ci`** (instead of `npm install`, [read about the difference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci/53325242#53325242))

   - this is [important because "`npm ci` will never write to package.json **or any of the package-locks**: installs are **essentially frozen**."](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-ci)
   - in other words, important for reproducibility, [which depends on package-lock.json function as "a single representation of a dependency tree](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) such that teammates, deployments, and continuous integration are **guaranteed to install exactly the same dependencies**"

---

For the record here is my entire error message, [similar to the one seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72056489/facing-issues-with-npm-i-and-installing-npm-packages) and [here](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/cypress-image-snapshot/issues/204)

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: test_install@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: cypress@9.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/cypress
npm ERR!   dev cypress@"^9.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer cypress@"^4.5.0" from cypress-plugin-snapshots@1.4.4
npm ERR! node_modules/cypress-plugin-snapshots
npm ERR!   dev cypress-plugin-snapshots@"^1.4.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\there\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\there\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-05T07_42_59_544Z-debug.log
```

<sup>1</sup>
Maybe my `overrides` does not work because of the bug mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70945777/1175496) and [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5850). Those bugs say `overrides` only work on a "fresh" install, when there is **no `node_modules` and no `package-lock.json`**. I will double-check this...

Answer (score -9):

Run this first

```
npm i -D @types/eslint@8.4.3
```

it will solve the issue

Comment: No, it doesn't.