# Pointing to a custom npm package version, two levels deep?

Tags: node.js, npm

When pointing to a different location of a package my app needs, I can usually just replace the version with `"depName": "githubUser/repoName"` and it works great.

But what should I do if the package I need to customize is itself a node module of some other package? e.g.

```
myapp
|_
  express.js
  |_
    send.js
```

I prefer to avoid publishing a fork of the first package, express in this example, just to use a modified version of send.

Comment: Have you tried [npm shrinkwrap](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html) as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17423915/1174467)?

Comment: Just tried and it works beautifully, thanks! Feel free to post this as the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)