# How to override a nested npm sub-dependency with a different package altogether (not just different package version number)?

Tags: node.js, npm

## Overview

I am having trouble resolving a ReDoS vulnerability identified by `npm audit`. My application has a nested sub-dependency `ansi-html` that is vulnerable to attack, but unfortunately, it seems that the [maintainers have gone AWOL](https://github.com/Tjatse/ansi-html/issues/19). As you can see in the comments section of that Github issue, to get around this problem, the community has made a fork of the repo called `ansi-html-community` located [here](https://github.com/mahdyar/ansi-html-community), which addresses this vulnerability.

Thus, I would like to replace all nested references of `ansi-html` with `ansi-html-community`.

## Problem

My normal strategy of using `npm-force-resolutions` does not seem to be able to override nested sub-dependencies with a different package altogether but rather only the same packages that are a different version number. I have researched this for several hours, but unfortunately, the only way I have found to fix this [would appear to be with yarn](https://github.com/Tjatse/ansi-html/issues/19#issuecomment-937690221), which I am now seriously considering using instead of npm. However, this is not ideal as our entire CI/CD pipeline is configured to use npm.

Does anyone know of any other way to accomplish nested sub-dependency package substitution/resolution without having to switch over to using yarn?

## Related Questions

These are questions of interest that I was able to find, but unfortunately, they tend to only discuss methods to override package version number, not the package itself.

###### Discusses how to override version number:

[How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)

###### Has a comment discussion about `npm shrinkwrap` (not ideal):

[npm - how to override a dependent package's dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239240/npm-how-to-override-a-dependent-packages-dependencies)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I figured it out. As of October 2021, the solution using `npm-force-resolutions` is actually very similar to how you would specify it using `yarn`. You just need to provide a link to the tarball where you would normally specify the overriding version number. Your resolutions section of `package.json` should look like this:

```json
"resolutions": {
    "ansi-html": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-html-community/-/ansi-html-community-0.0.8.tgz"
}
```

To find the link to the tarball, use the following command, modifying your registry as necessary:

```
npm view ansi-html-community dist.tarball --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Also, note that for `npm-force-resolutions` to work when you run `npm install`, you will need a `preinstall` entry under the `scripts` section of `package.json`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  }
```

Comment: It seems like this doesn't seem to work for me. npm ls ansi-html still returns the regular ansi-html@0.0.7 version. Do you just use the standard preinstall script?

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean that it didn't work. As long as your `ansi-html` is ultimately getting resolved to `ansi-html-community` you should be good. If you haven't already try deleting your package-lock.json and regenerating it. Then search for instances of `ansi-html` and verify what it is getting resolved to.

Comment: Running `npm-force-resolutions` as a `preinstall` `script` (via stackoverflow.com/a/68095189/132735) didn't yield the awaited results (having the `tarball` as the `resolved` entry). Running it manually instead (`npx npm-force-resolutions`) and then, of course, pushing the `lockfile` did the trick. Or one can just move to the latest yarn where native selective resolutions support exists. Apparently npm is also cooking an `overrides` feature -- https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/accepted/0036-overrides.md :>

Comment: But required package is not installed inside node_module. it jst updates the package-lock.json file.

Comment: It will do both. The idea is once you are in a CI environment you can simply use `npm ci` at which point `node_modules` will be made directly from your `package-lock.json` (and nothing else). However, when you run `npm install` locally, it will update both your `node_modules` and your `package-lock.json` (assuming you have set up your `preinstall` in the `scripts` section of your `package.json` as shown at the end of my post). If this is not happening for you for some reason, consider completely deleting your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` first and then trying again.

Answer (score -1):

For those, who needs the same solution with yarn, just add this to your package.json

```js
 "resolutions": {
    "ansi-html": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-html-community/-/ansi-html-community-0.0.8.tgz"
  }
```

and then run `yarn install`

you might also do after this, if it won't work immediately

`rm yarn.lock`

`yarn install`