# NativeScript 8.0.0: NPM vulnerabilites switching between "3 high" to "30 high"

Tags: npm, webpack, nativescript, nativescript-vue, npm-audit

I am currently working on a NativeScript project that uses NativeScript core ~8.0.0 and I just ran an `npm install` and realized that there are 3 high vulnerabilities. When I try to fix them using `npm audit fix` (even with `--force` flag) I end up having 30 hight vulnerabilites. Again `npm audit fix`leads to the original 3 high again.

These seem to be due to `@nativescript/webpack:5.0.0` which is the current version but relies on a vulnerable version of `@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin`.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Here is the detailed output of `npm audit`:

```
Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-whgm-jr23-g3j9
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @nativescript/webpack@4.1.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/ansi-html
  @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin  <=0.5.0-rc.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-html
    @nativescript/webpack  >=5.0.0-alpha.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    node_modules/@nativescript/webpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Nervermind, `ns migrate` did the trick.

Still if anyone is facing a similar problem with the `ansi-html` package there is a solution for that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69726845/6489123).