# Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html

Tags: node.js, angular

I am getting one of the High vulnerability in angular project is 'Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html'.
[image]

I have got few more such type of High vulnerabilities but those are fixed by adding 'resolutions' section under package.json file and under scripts section added "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions". Which I had fixed those vulnerabilities came Patched in with version like 'Patched in    │ >=4.0.1  ' . But this this came with 'No patch available'.
So I am getting bit confuse to fix this. Does anyone have idea, how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you aren't using `ansi-html` directly but rely on dependencies that use it, you should instead set up a `resolutions` section in `package.json`. (You should never edit `package-lock.json` directly since it is regenerated every time you run `npm install`). You just need to provide a link to the tarball where you would normally specify the overriding version number. Your resolutions section of `package.json` should look like this:

```json
"resolutions": {
    "ansi-html": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-html-community/-/ansi-html-community-0.0.8.tgz"
}
```

Please refer to this post for more details:

[How to override a nested npm sub-dependency with a different package altogether (not just different package version number)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69548370/how-to-override-a-nested-npm-sub-dependency-with-a-different-package-altogether/69591894#69591894)

Answer (score 0):

Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html (CVE-2021-23424) is a vulnerability that won’t be fixed by the project’s author, **since it’s been abandoned and there won’t be a patched version of ansi-html**.

You just have to go to package-lock.json and find the line with:

```
"ansi-html": {
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-html/-/ansi-html-0.0.7.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-gTWEAhliqenm/QOflA0S9WynhZ4="
```

And replace with this:

```
"ansi-html-community": {
  "version": "0.0.8",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-html-community/-/ansi-html-community-0.0.8.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-1APHAyr3+PCamwNw3bXCPp4HFLONZt/yIH0sZp0/469KWNTEy+qN5jQ3GVX6DMZ1UXAi34yVwtTeaG/HpBuuzw=="
```

And this line in the same file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ansi-html": "^0.0.7",
```

Replace with:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ansi-html-community": "^0.0.8",
```

Then just type `npm update` and thats it.

You can get more info in this [link](https://blog.mahdyar.me/2021/09/23/how-to-fix-ansi-html-vulnerability/).

And check the entire commit [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/commit/36fd21477dac5131ec266cc1d717d87051f10a2b).

Comment: You should never edit `package-lock.json` directly. Changes will be lost every time `npm install` is run, which is inconvenient and can lead to unexpected behavior. `npm-force-resolutions` should be used instead as a temporary fix until the maintainers of the dependencies you are using update their packages to use `ansi-html-community`.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your Angular to the latest version (Angular 13 is the latest version for now) will solve your problem! Cheers!

Comment: I still have the same errors on my `npm audit` even though I'm updated to Angular 13

Comment: Interesting... If you updated correctly (use [link](https://update.angular.io) for it please), you have `"ansi-html-community": "^0.0.8"` (not "ansi-html" version:0.0.7) in your package-lock.json.
So, in your case, remove node-modules folder, package-lock.json and do 'npm install'.