# How to fix not supported error with node.js ansi-html

Tags: node.js

I was getting an error from Github about ansi-html vuanrablity. I ran an npm update on my local install, and it said that there was no fix for it. The only thing I could find about how to fix this is this link.
[Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676335/uncontrolled-resource-consumption-in-ansi-html)

However, when following these instructions I then got a high severity warning that says "*87 packages are looking for funding run `npm fund` for details*". I do that and a list of URLs is revealed. It also says to run npm audit which returns "*Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html - [https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-whgm-jr23-g3j9*"](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-whgm-jr23-g3j9*%22) Any help on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: so, uhm... what was the "not supported" error? you mentioned the "fund" notice, which isn't an error or a warning, and an audit notice that pointed out a vulnerability that the library authors haven't resolved... I mean, you could fix it for them and submit a pull request?

Answer (score 1):

The funding message is unrelated. This is a unique case in that the maintainers for `ansi-html` are inactive so you will need to resolve to another package called `ansi-html-community`.

To fix the vulnerability for `ansi-html` you will need to use `npm-force-resolutions` as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69591894/12649786

Comment: I did this and I still get an error. I would have put the comment on the post you referred to, but I cannot comment on that one. My terminal is saying `Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-whgm-jr23-g3j9
No fix available
node_modules/ansi-html`what that means.