# Github action: npm install -> Error: Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: bash, github, npm, npm-install, github-actions

I have this GitHub action workflow that have been working for over a year. Suddenly I get error when I get to the step that runs 'npm install'. I really have no clue why the error is triggered. Would really appreciate someone helping or at least just pointing me in right direction. If you need some more data just tell me I will edit the question.

I have tried updating some packages and also the `npm update` command. But no good:

```
Run npm install
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/projsiteWebApp/projsiteWebApp/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /home/runner/work/projsiteWebApp/projsiteWebApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/runner/work/projsiteWebApp/projsiteWebApp/node_modules/node-sass/build'
npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-
```

(some more error message in between here but had to cut off due to too many characters)

```
npm ERR!                                       remove_cv
npm ERR! /home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: ‘remove_cv_t’ is not a member of ‘std’
npm ERR! /home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: note: suggested alternative: ‘remove_cv’
npm ERR!              !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                       remove_cv
npm ERR! /home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
npm ERR!              !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                                   ^
npm ERR! /home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:63: error: ‘::Perform’ has not been declared
npm ERR!              !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                                                ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! /home/runner/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:63: note: suggested alternative: ‘herror’
npm ERR!              !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                                                ^~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                                                herror
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/runner/work/projsiteWebApp/projsiteWebApp/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-1064-azure
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/runner/work/projsiteWebApp/projsiteWebApp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/runner/work/projsiteWebApp/projsiteWebApp/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-12-13T20_05_37_396Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something in your project is using [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), which contains libsass which is deprecated

If it is a direct dependency, you can just switch over to [Dart Sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass), and things mostly should just work the same. If it is a transitive dependency that is requiring `node-sass`, you can try to update it by updating your direct dependencies that depend on it. Alternatively, if you're using yarn, you can try to [change it with selective version resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions)

If you couldn't manage to switch to using `dart-sass` and have to deal with the C++ gyp build error, I would probably check to make sure that the particular version of node-sass you're using is compatible with the current c++ compiler you currently have installed. Maybe your compiler became too old because `libsass` (and in turn, `node-sass`) decided to up their language requirements?

Edit:
Try using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69548370/how-to-override-a-nested-npm-sub-dependency-with-a-different-package-altogether/69591894) (since you are using npm) for resolving the `node-sass` that is inside vue-mj-daterangepicker to something else. You can change to a newer version or by using the "dart-sass" package. If you use the latter, g++ wouldn't error since dart-sass doesn't use c++. You could also use the "sass" package, since the `sass` and `dart-sass` npm pacakges are essentially the same

Maybe something like the following in your `package.json`... (not tested)

```json
"resolutions": {
  "node-sass": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sass/-/node-sass-7.0.0.tgz"
},
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

or

```json
"resolutions": {
  "node-sass": "https://registry.npmjs.org/dart-sass/-/dart-sass-1.25.0.tgz"
},
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

Comment: No iam using npm and not yarn. The node-sass is transitive dependency. How do i update a transitive dependency did not know you could do that. i tried "npm update node-sass" but nothing happends. And by the way in my package.lock if i search(ctrl+f) on libsass i dont find nothing. Do you really think it is libsass that is the obsticle here? @edwin much appriciate the answer

Comment: Oh i just saw that you said update it by updating your direct dependencies that depend on it... will try

Comment: I don't think libsass would show up in your `package-lock.json` since its not an npm package; `node-sass` should be in there though. `npm update node-sass` likely doesn't work because it is not a direct dependency. Also for npm, it appears there is [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69548370/how-to-override-a-nested-npm-sub-dependency-with-a-different-package-altogether/69591894) for pining transitive dependencies, but I am unsure of how well it works

Comment: And to be a bit more clear, I think it's `node-sass` thats the issue. If the `dart-sass` package was used instead of `node-sass`, then `libsass` wouldn't have to be compiled, and you wouldn't be getting those g++ errors

Comment: okej so i tried uninstalling the direct dependency that had node-sass as dependency. Just to se if it was there the issue was. I tried the github action workflow again. And it worked. But that direct dependency(https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-mj-daterangepicker) dont have any more updates?? can i update the node-sass inside somehow? @edwin

Comment: Yeah, I edited my reply for how you can change that dependency. I'll also add that `vue-mj-daterangepicker` does the _wrong_ thing by specifically declaring `node-sass`, `sass-loader`, `vue`, `pug-plain-loader`, etc. as subdependencies - so it's the fault of who authored that package

Comment: Yes i updated the node-sass. Used your first example. Works like a charm. You my guy is a king!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is happening is because libsass seems to be set up to use the C++11 standard when it builds, but `std::remove_cv_t` was only introduced as part of the C++14 standard (I think some compilers like MSVC may have introduced it earlier than that).  An easy fix is to set the CXXFLAGS environment variable before you run `npm install`. e.g. `CXXFLAGS="--std=c++14" npm install`