# `npm install` how to track the packages which issue warnings?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is any easy way in `npm` to track from which packages these kind of dependency warnings came from? Packages in the warnings is for sure not the top level ones.

I'm currently on npm v3.6.0 (node 5.6.0).

[image: Warnings when <code>npm install</code>]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running `npm list` in your project directory will give you a dependency tree, and a simple text search for the deprecated packages will indicate where they came from.

As a workaround to deprecation issues, you could use npm-shrinkwrap ([example usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17423915/1446919)).

Comment: Thanks, `npm list` is probably closest thing, although I was hoping to have something like `npm list --warnings` which filter out toplevel packages which are depend on packages that throwing warnings and indicates this packages...

Answer (score 1):

I think [`npm explain`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-explain?v=true) is what you are looking for. Below is the console result when I look-up a package named `stable` in my current project. It indicates the package is installed by one of my dev dependencies named `react-app-rewired`.

```
$ npm explain stable
stable@0.1.8
node_modules/stable
  stable@"^0.1.8" from svgo@1.3.2
  node_modules/svgo
    svgo@"^1.2.2" from @svgr/plugin-svgo@5.5.0
    node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo@"^5.5.0" from @svgr/webpack@5.5.0
      node_modules/@svgr/webpack
        @svgr/webpack@"5.5.0" from react-scripts@4.0.3
        node_modules/react-scripts
          react-scripts@"4.0.3" from the root project
          peer react-scripts@">=2.1.3" from react-app-rewired@2.1.9
          node_modules/react-app-rewired
            dev react-app-rewired@"^2.1.9" from the root project
    svgo@"^1.0.0" from postcss-svgo@4.0.3
    node_modules/postcss-svgo
      postcss-svgo@"^4.0.3" from cssnano-preset-default@4.0.8
      node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
        cssnano-preset-default@"^4.0.8" from cssnano@4.1.11
        node_modules/cssnano
          cssnano@"^4.1.10" from optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.4
          node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
            optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@"5.0.4" from react-scripts@4.0.3
            node_modules/react-scripts
              react-scripts@"4.0.3" from the root project
              peer react-scripts@">=2.1.3" from react-app-rewired@2.1.9
              node_modules/react-app-rewired
                dev react-app-rewired@"^2.1.9" from the root project
```