# How do I override nested dependencies with `yarn`?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-shrinkwrap, yarnpkg

If my package has these dependencies

```
{ "name": "my-package",
  "dependencies": { "foobar":"~1.0.3", "baz":"2.0.9" }
```

And the `foobar` package has these dependencies

```
{ "name": "foobar",
  "dependencies": { "baz":"^2.0.0" }
```

and the most recently released version of `baz` is `2.1.0`, the first run of `yarn` will install `baz@2.1.0` in `foobar/node_modules`.

How do I force yarn to use the `baz@2.0.9` package for `foobar`?

My understanding is that this would be possible using `npm shrinkwrap` (a la [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)).

---

The summary of my question probably is: Yarn creates repeatable, deterministic installations, but how do I customize that installation?

Comment: Did you guys ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @atomman actually I think I was wrong in the basis for this question. Yarn had determined that there was an incompatibility between my top level package version number and another dependency's sub-dependency. So it correctly decided give the dependency its own version of that library.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Although I'm not sure I agree, as baz@2.0.9 would satisfy all requirement. Though it could be seen as a feature that yarn always provides the most up-to-date dependency for sub-modules. I do however feel like yarn should provide a dependency-resolution mechanism for these cases, but thats another discussion. :)

Comment: @atomman oh, yes, i agree with you (and with the premise in my question) however I think the real problem I was *actually* having was subtly different from the one i described in my question.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

If you do in fact have a sub-dependency that is overly restrictive in what versions it will accept, you *can* override them using yarn.

**UPDATED EDIT:** Yarn now, as of 1.0, [officially supports](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) the "resolutions" block. So the way to override resolutions is to just add a block like this to `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
      "package-a": "2.0.0",
      "package-b": "5.0.0",
      "package-c": "1.5.2"
}
```

You'll get warnings for "incompatible" versions sometimes, but I find that some packages (like socket.io) are *overly* restrictive in what version they accept, and so I'll happily select the latest version when it doesn't actually break things.

### Original but outdated answer below.

It sounds like the original question wasn't exactly correct, but the original question *was* in fact the one I wanted answered, and I found an answer, so here it is for posterity:

I'm using the socket.io library, and it has `component-emitter` as a dependency. But it has a pair of versions that it requires. This is what the yarn.lock file looked like before I changed anything:

```
component-emitter@1.1.2:
  version "1.1.2"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/component-emitter/-/component-emitter-1.1.2.tgz#296594f2753daa63996d2af08d15a95116c9aec3"

component-emitter@1.2.0:
  version "1.2.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/component-emitter/-/component-emitter-1.2.0.tgz#ccd113a86388d06482d03de3fc7df98526ba8efe"
```

So it was including two copies of the component emitter in my client code. I looked, and there didn't appear to be any breaking changes between 1.1.2 and 1.2.0 (or 1.2.1, which was current). I first tried just changing the yarn.lock file:

```
component-emitter@1.2.1, component-emitter@^1.2.1, component-emitter@1.1.2:
  version "1.2.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/component-emitter/-/component-emitter-1.2.1.tgz#137918d6d78283f7df7a6b7c5a63e140e69425e6"
```

This worked, but the file has warnings about it being autogenerated, meaning that every single update or new package I add will stomp on this change. A bit of searching found the `yarn --flat` option, which will force yarn to choose no more than one of each package in the entire project. That seems like overkill to me, since I'm sure there are actual cases of incompatibility between older and newer packages. I just wanted to eliminate a redundant package from my client code, to make the download smaller; I still want the development packages to all *work* correctly.

But in the docs to [yarn --flat](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-flat) I found a reference to a "resolutions" block that can go in package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
  "package-a": "2.0.0",
  "package-b": "5.0.0",
  "package-c": "1.5.2"
}
```

So I tried putting `"component-emitter" : "1.2.1"` in a new "resolutions" block in my package.json, and it in fact flattened component-emitter to 1.2.1 for all places that required it, and now I have only one copy in my client code.

(And now the `resolutions` block is completely supported in `yarn`, so you don't even need to use `--flat`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. So i guess the solution is at least in part is "edit the yarn.lock file", which is what i was afraid of doing in the first place. But it makes sense that yarn wont go out of its way to nuke that file.

Comment: Worked for me without touching `package.json`. Had `async-busboy` dep and wanted to change the version of its sub-dep - `busboy`. So I just replaced `busboy "0.2.13"` with `busboy "mscdex/busboy#76c3d58"`, ran `yarn install`, and voila, everything works. Strangely, yarn didn't update the "busboy" block in the lock file, but that doesn't bother me too much, as long as it works.

Comment: Sure, as long as you use only yarn ever. If someone else comes along and runs `npm install`, though, they'll get the wrong version. I *think* that if you modify both it might still work, though not as fine-grained as with yarn -- and if what you're installing is a dependency of another package that you add, the "resolutions" should at least override the new package dependencies so that you don't end up with many versions of the same package.

Comment: This does **not** work in a robust long term way. As soon as `yarn upgrade` is run, the `yarn.lock` file is overwritten, and the `resolutions` section in your `package.json` is ignored by nested dependencies.

Comment: @MichaelPlotke Reproduced. Sure enough. So beware global `yarn upgrade` calls. I've only upgraded packages individually, but I can understand why you'd want to just "upgrade everything." But yes, you'll have to check anything you've explicitly overriden if you do that.

Comment: @MichaelPlotke And now Yarn 1.0 officially supports the "resolutions" section, so my answer works again. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with renamed packages. For example, `babel-core` which was renamed to `@babel/core` in its newer version is impossible to override using resolutions afaik.

Comment: For renamed packages, I'd put in a feature request (or star one if it exists already) for yarn. I'd actually use that functionality myself, since there are times that I want my OWN fork of a package to be used as a dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when using yarn workspaces. It is such a PITA if one is using TypeScript typings from @types/ namespace. It is common to declare their dependencies with asterisk "*"!

Comment: My project uses create-react-app and has redux installed. Redux package has a fixed dependency on immer@8.0.1 which is being flagged with a vulnerability with blackduck scanner. I tried using resolutions to force it to 9.0.6, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I tried everything on the internet for the issue I'm facing while deploying my Nodejs Application in Jenkins throwing vulnerabilities in SEC:CSS (Prisma). To update the peer dependencies this is the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 87):

This is now possible with yarn's [selective version resolution feature](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/4105).

In your project's *main* (root) `package.json`, use `resolutions`:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "foobar/**/baz": "2.0.9"
  }
```

This overrides package `foobar`'s (and any other packages under it) version of `baz`, forcing it to be version 2.0.9.

Comment: Does not work with workspaces :( See my comment above.

Comment: @Marecky it does work with workspaces, but you have to put the resolutions in the top level package.json

Comment: Problem for me is the dependent deprecated package in use has been renamed/replaced with something entirely different. So `parent` lists `libA` as dependent. But `libA` is deprecated and renamed to `libB`. How do I tell `parent` to use `libB`?

Comment: @steezeburger it took me weeks to find your comment to solved a problem that took me days :D are you still active and willing to post this as an answer? I know this whole thing is years old, but still a badly documented issue.

Comment: It does not work in Yarn 3. Using `**` results in the following error when running `yarn`: `Expected "@", [^/@], or end of input but "/" found`

Comment: It appears the glob syntax `**` isn't/wasn't supported. Following the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest#resolutions), Yarn is happy if removing the globs - which is arguably better, be it annoying if the dependencies are highly nested.

Comment: @MarkLopez how would you add a resolution for a highly nested dependency?

Comment: You would need to specify the full dependency path @coler-j, each level separated with a `/`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This is now deprecated, please read this answer instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46615878/2398593

---

[@SomeCallMeTime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378227/somecallmetim)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082766/2398593) is great and we've been doing that for month at work.

Unfortunately, **this is not possible anymore since the v0.24.x** (see that [comment](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2763#issuecomment-301700178)).

There's an opened [PR on Github](https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/pull/68) with an RFC proposal to have a simple way of handling that use case without having to keep an eye on the generated lockfile.

Comment: My answer works again, as of 1.0. See updated edit. :)

Comment: NOTE: this answer is outdated

Comment: Outdated answer

Comment: I edited the post 8 months ago to write at the very top `EDIT: This is now deprecated, please read this answer instead` so... I don't think that comment is necessary Pep :)