# Use the exact version of lib from NPM

Tags: node.js, git, express, npm, shrinkwrap

We use the following lib as dependencies in our project
https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia

In this lib the `package.json` they use express 
https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/blob/master/package.yaml

```
dependencies:
  express: '>=5.0.0-0 <6.0.0-0'
```

which is very problematic and we cannot use it since version 5 (5.0.0-alpha.1) is not official outside
https://github.com/expressjs/express
the npm released version is `4.14`  my question is the following

1. What is the sense to declare dependencies in this way which is not
   released yet?
2. Is there a way somehow to restricted the version to 4.14 or other 5
   version (not alfa version ) without doing fork to this repo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions) suggests using a partial npm-shrinkwrap.json to achieve what you want.

According to [Allow partial npm-shrinkwrap.json to only force *some* dependencies](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7108), this is supported in npm@3.

Comment: but this is external dep, for example I use in my project os like express which is using some other os like ath-to-regexp which use version alfa how can I solve it from my module?

Comment: ok 1+ the problem is when you put this srinkwarp dep it download only the package you put inside this file and I want do restricted just one lib and the other should be download as before , how can I do that can you please provide example ?

Comment: I mean if the parent lib use to child libs (child1&child2) and you put in the  npm-shrinkwrap.json only child1 restricted version, you dont get child 2 when you install the packages why and if there is workaround for this ?

Comment: This is the exact issue discussed in https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7108. Read that whole thread carefully to understand the ins and outs of this. It's a little tricky.

Comment: I read it and didn't got it...can you please give the reference?how it's can be managed...thanks!

Comment: If you aren't able to get it working with npm shrinkwrap, you can consider trying to use yarn (https://yarnpkg.com/) instead of npm. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226639/how-do-i-override-nested-dependencies-with-yarn. See https://www.sitepoint.com/yarn-vs-npm for a godd overview of the differences between npm and yarn.