# After updating yarn, react app is failing to compile due to node-module related import error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, web-development-server

It was all working ok, then everything changed when I updated yarn. I get this error in the yarn server terminal window: `Failed to compile. ./node_modules/react-overlays/esm/Dropdown.js Attempted import error: 'useUncontrolledProp' is not exported from 'uncontrollable'.`

and this in the localhost window thing: `./node_modules/react-overlays/esm/Dropdown.js Attempted import error: 'useUncontrolledProp' is not exported from 'uncontrollable'.`

I just am lost when it comes to those node modules, and could really use some direction in navigating this unfortunate situation.

Comment: Can you try deleting the `/node_moudles` folder. Then run the command `yarn` in the root directory of your app to re-install the `node_modules`?

Comment: Bless your heart! That worked!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem seems to be related to *react-bootstrap* requiring `uncontrollable==^7.0.0` and yarn installing that *exact* version.

I've fixed it by:

1. `yarn add uncontrollable@7.1.1`
2. remove node_modules directory: in my case `rmdir /q /s node_modules`
3. edit `package.json` to add this: `{ "resolutions": "uncontrollable": "7.1.1" }` (don't forget the `,` if it is not the last item)
4. `yarn`   (to re-install all packages)

The point 3. prevents dependencies to use other versions of `uncontrollable` according to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082766/1033012 .

---

Extra info:

Also, if I ran: `yarn list uncontrollable` between step 1 and 2, output was:

```
yarn list v1.22.4
warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
warning Filtering by arguments is deprecated. Please use the pattern option instead.
├─ react-bootstrap@1.3.0
│  └─ uncontrollable@7.0.0
├─ react-overlays@4.1.0
│  └─ uncontrollable@7.0.0
└─ uncontrollable@7.1.1
Done in 0.90s.
```

But that was fixed with steps 2 to 4 with leaved system like this: `yarn list uncontrollable`

```
yarn list v1.22.4
warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
warning Filtering by arguments is deprecated. Please use the pattern option instead.
└─ uncontrollable@7.1.1
Done in 0.99s.
```