# react-native-webview Typescript error: 'WebView' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typeerror, react-native-webview

I am trying to set up a simple React Native app using Expo with TypeScript that shows a WebView. My `App.tsx` file contains the following:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <WebView
            style={styles.container}
            source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/' }}
        />
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    },
});
```

This code works correctly, but the TypeScript compiler throws an error at the WebView component.

```
App.tsx:7:4 - error TS2786: 'WebView' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'WebView<{ style: { marginTop: number; }; source: { uri: string; }; }>' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'import("C:/example/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'React.ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
          Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, props

7   <WebView
     ~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

I am using the following versions of my dependencies:

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "expo": "~44.0.0",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "17.0.1",
        "react-native": "0.64.3",
        "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
        "react-native-webview": "11.15.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
        "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
        "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
        "typescript": "~4.3.5"
    }
}
```

How can I correct this error?

Comment: What if you put it inside View?

Comment: @Marat I get the same error.

Comment: You can try to make your App class component, just to see if the error still occurs

Comment: @Marat That does appear to fix the TypeScript error, is there a way to write the component as a function instead of a class without the error?

Comment: Did the code help?

Comment: Odd this used to work for me.  Something seems to have changed over the last few months since I haven't touched my webview code.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspiction you may be using Storybook, which includes a dependency on @reach/router which creates a dependency on @types/reach__router which requires @types/react@18 causing you to have more than one @types/react@18  on your path.

Answer (score 9):

You would get this error if you had more than one `@types/react` library in your `node_modules`.  In my case this was caused by Storybook which included @reach/router which included @types/reach__router which included @types/react@18 different from my current Expo version.

Using [How do I override nested dependencies with `yarn`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226639/how-do-i-override-nested-dependencies-with-yarn)

I added the matching version

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21"
  },
```

and regenerated to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries don't support typescript. In this case you can use the comment
`// @ts-ignore` in front of the error to let TS ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that:

```
const App: FC = () => {
 return (
     <WebView
         style={styles.container}
         source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/' }}
     />
 );
}

export default App;
```