# how to specify typescript version to ts-loader?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I'm installing [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) to work with webpack.

Does someone know how to choose which typescript version to use ?

No matter what I do, I always get a message saying

```
ts-loader: Using typescript@1.8.10 and /app/tsconfig.json
```

I intend to use typescript@2 but I have no clue how to tell ts-loader to use the proper version...

Thanks

Comment: Add typescript@2 to your devDependencies. ts-loader should it use without any configuration. If you don't, it'll use globally installed typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your answer is not sufficient for those who use react-scripts-ts or any other dependencies which require the older version of the typescript. I have added to my package dependency typescript ^2.6.2, but ts-loader still shows typescript 2.5.3, because "react-scripts-ts" has a dependency "typescript":"~2.5.3", so somehow that dependency takes precedence.

The actual solution that I found is creating [`npm-shrinkwrap.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17423915/508797) file where I override subdependency of react-scripts-ts to the correct dependency, something like this:

```
{
    "dependencies":
    {
        "react-scripts-ts":
        {
            "dependencies":{
                "typescript": { "version": "2.6.2" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After creating this file, I remove folder `node_modules` and execute `npm install`

If you're not sure which package in your dependency tree depends on specific version of some package, you can find it in `package-lock.json` file

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it

It turns out typescript was installed by npm as a dependency. And by default it's 1.8

Adding typescript@2 to package.json properly set the typescript version

Comment: didn't work for me, I have specified 2.6.2 in my package.json, but ts-loader still shows 2.5.2 :-(