# Cannot read property 'line' of undefined at originalPosition in gulp-clean-css plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-clean-css

As mentioned in the question, when I launch `gulp build` I get the following error:

```
C:\dev\work\viewAngular\web\node_modules\gulp-clean-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\input-source-map-tracker.js:37
if (originalPosition.line === null && line > 1 && selectorFallbacks > 0) {
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined
    at originalPosition 
    For (C:\dev\work\viewAngular\web\node_modules\gulp-clean-css\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\input-source-map-tracker.js:37:23)
```

I dont know where this is coming up from since I didn't make any changes to `gulp-clean-css` files or anything related.

I also launched multiple times: `bower update`, `bower install`, `npm install`.

Comment: This is likely to be an issue with updated transitive dependency.. you might be able to solve it by degrading your dependencies or http://stackoverflow.com/a/17423915 might as well be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem. My issue was that I had a devDependencies like this:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.3",
    ...
 }
```

This bumped `gulp-clean-css`to version 2.4.0 which crashed my build. Removing the `^` forced the older version and made my build run again.

Now it's time up upgrade my dependencies, but at least I know what was failing...