# npm run build:prod error clean-css

Tags: angular, npm, gulp

I am getting a strange error today when i run npm run build:prod.

```
 "build:prod": "ng build --prod --aot=false --preserve-symlinks"
```

The error is like..

```
92% chunk asset optimizationC:\Projects\Latest_Feb26\ASSURE.OdyssEYGen2\FrontEnd\OdyssEY-UI-Host\node_modules\clean-css
\lib\reader\input-source-map-tracker.js:37
  if (originalPosition.line === null && line > 1 && selectorFallbacks > 0) {
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined
    at originalPositionFor (C:\Projects\Latest_Feb26\ASSURE.OdyssEYGen2\FrontEnd\OdyssEY-UI-Host\node_modules\clean-css\
lib\reader\input-source-map-tracker.js:37:23)
```

The build was working fine always and not sure why i am getting this strange error today.

I did deleted node_modules, npm i and npm run build:prod

Can anyone help me ?

Also there is something on the OUTPUT tab in visual studio code:

```
Failed to load the ESLint library for the document c:\Projects\Latest_Feb26\ASSURE.OdyssEYGen2\FrontEnd\OdyssEY-UI-Host\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\input-source-map-tracker.js

To use ESLint in this workspace please install eslint using 'npm install eslint' or globally using 'npm install -g eslint'.
You need to reopen the workspace after installing eslint.
```

Thanks

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494864/cannot-read-property-line-of-undefined-at-originalposition-in-gulp-clean-css-p) may help resolve your first issue - it seems to encounter the same error message. My guess is that a newer version of [clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-css) is now getting installed and that's why your build task has broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 : ng build -- prod fails due to clean-css : Cannot read property 'line' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033898/angular-5-ng-build-prod-fails-due-to-clean-css-cannot-read-property-line)

Answer (score 0):

replace the code in node_modules/clean-css/lib/reader/input-source-map-tracker.js with the following ;)

```
var SourceMapConsumer = require('source-map').SourceMapConsumer;

function inputSourceMapTracker() {
  var maps = {};

  return {
    all: all.bind(null, maps),
    isTracking: isTracking.bind(null, maps),
    originalPositionFor: originalPositionFor.bind(null, maps),
    track: track.bind(null, maps)
  };
}

function all(maps) {
  return maps;
}

function isTracking(maps, source) {
  return source in maps;
}

function originalPositionFor(maps, metadata, range, selectorFallbacks) {
  var line = metadata[0];
  var column = metadata[1];
  var source = metadata[2];
  var position = {
    line: line,
    column: column + range
  };
  var originalPosition;

  while (!originalPosition && position.column > column) {
    position.column--;
    originalPosition = maps[source].originalPositionFor(position);
  }

  if (originalPosition && originalPosition.line === null && line > 1 && selectorFallbacks > 0) {
    return originalPositionFor(maps, [line - 1, column, source], range, selectorFallbacks - 1);
  }

  return (originalPosition && originalPosition.line) !== null ?
    toMetadata(originalPosition) :
    metadata;
}

function toMetadata(asHash) {
  if(asHash){
    return [asHash.line, asHash.column, asHash.source];
  }
}

function track(maps, source, data) {
  maps[source] = new SourceMapConsumer(data);
}

module.exports = inputSourceMapTracker;
```