# Proper way to fix potential security vulnerability in a dependency defined in package-lock.json

Tags: github, npm, package-lock.json

Github has given me this error on one of my repositories.

```
We found a potential security vulnerability in one of your dependencies.
A dependency defined in ./package-lock.json has known security vulnerabilities 
and should be updated.
```

The dependency is not defined in our `package.json` file. To my understanding it isn't good practice to delete the `package-lock.json` file and regenerate it. However, I cannot see any other way to fix this issue. If I dismiss this security vulnerability it will appear again a couple of days later. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053991/github-potential-security-vulnerability-error-for-hoek-node-module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github potential security vulnerability error for hoek node module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053991/github-potential-security-vulnerability-error-for-hoek-node-module)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

New: now, with npm@6 you can directly run

```
npm audit fix
```

---

Old answer:

You should try to identify the problematic package's name, and then run

```
npm install package-name
```

replacing package-name, obviously.

This will install the latest version of the package, and very often, the latest version has fixed the security issue. If you have a constraint on version (eg: 1.2), you can always try to:

```
npm install package-name@^1.2
```

and the latest patched version will be installed

Comment: ...and to 'identify the problematic package's name' you can run `npm ls vulnerability-name`. This lists the vulnerability depedendents, which you can then update/install. (as mentioned rather unclearly in @RileyManda's answer)

Comment: npm audit fix cleanly fixes this issue for me now.

Comment: It will add `package-name` in `dependencies` of `package.json`. I don't want this.

Comment: Everyone please use the above mentioned npm audit fix

Comment: If the vulnerability is deeper in the dependency tree, you can use npm's overrides property (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions/70396201#70396201)

Comment: yes @s6mike and `resolutions` with yarn

Comment: "npm ERR! audit endpoint returned an error"

Answer (score 9):

To resolve this:

**Solution1:**
First find the vulnerability:Using your terminal:
 **cd into your project**, then run **"npm ls hoek"**

And finally:
**npm install bcrypt@latest**

Then push the updated project to git.(i.e perform a fresh commit).

**Solution 2:**

if the first option/solution does not resolve the issue.Change the version manually in your package-lock.json.
Change your version manually from 2.16.3 to 4.2.1

```
"hoek": {
      "version":  "4.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-4.2.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-ILt0A9POo5jpHcRxCo/xuCdKJe0=",
      "dev": true
```

Then update your project on GitHub(commit/push)
Just make sure every hoek version occurrence in your package-lock.json version is changed to 4.2.1

Alternatively if you can figure out a way to change the hoek version/update hoek using npm,will make things much simpler.(something like : **npm update @hoek..version**)..or uninstall the specific dependency then reinstall it using bower or npm.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue with a lodash security vulnerability, in a project I was building with yarn.  Github flagged these as security concerns.

I tried the answer from @rileymanda above, using a terminal: cd into project, then run `npm ls lodash`.

This uncovered that in my case, the error was in *react-scripts*.  Quick Google for issues with react-scripts and lodash uncovered that this was a known issue.

I tried various things to fix via yarn - all with no success.  `npm ls lodash` still showed the vulnerable version of lodash in use.

Having read [Matt Turnbull's blog about improvements to npm](https://iamturns.com/yarn-vs-npm-2018/) I switched from yarn back to npm.  (Delete `yarn.lock`, delete `./node_modules`. Run `npm install`). `npm ls lodash` now showed the latest dependency versions being used - hurrah!  Committed to github, and it was now happy that the vulnerability had gone.

It looks like yarn may be struggling to unpick such issues (or isn't intended to).

If you're getting this issue when building with yarn, then try switching [back] to npm!

Answer (score 3):

> To my understanding it isn't good practice to delete the package-lock.json file and regenerate it.

Yet, this is what is usually done in this instance.
See for example [angular/angular-cli issue 8534](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8534), which is resolved by [PR 8535](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/8535).
That leads a dependent project like [`frees-io/freestyle-opscenter-webclient`](https://github.com/frees-io/freestyle-opscenter-webclient) to [update its `package-lock.json`: PR 31](https://github.com/frees-io/freestyle-opscenter-webclient/pull/31).

Comment: Regeneration of package-lock.json seems doesn't solve the probelm

Comment: @xianshenglu OK, I'll leave the answer there in case it does help others.

Comment: I'm receiving the warning for a package-lock in an old commit. How on earth am I to fix something in the history without rewriting it?

Comment: @destoryer That I don't know: try and ask a new question with more detail (OS, version of npm, ...)

Comment: That fixed my issue. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: "It depends." There's a lot of confusion with `package-lock.json` because the philosophy about it has changed. See https://medium.com/coinmonks/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8

Answer (score 3):

The simplest/easiest way to fix this is:

1. `npm install <dep>`
2. `npm uninstall <dep>`
3. `npm update`
4. `npm install`

From: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48783#issuecomment-384873041

Comment: Mine is only in dependencies (package-lock.json) so completing steps 1 and 2 is enough to fix my issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

> known security vulnerabilities  and should be updated.

Since May 23rd, 2019, you now have "[**Dependabot: Automated security fixes**](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-23-dependabot-automated-security-fixes/)"

> Through the integration of Dependabot, we’ve released automated security fixes as a public beta.
>
> Automated security fixes are pull requests generated by GitHub to fix security vulnerabilities.
> **They automate a tedious part of the workflow and make it easy for developers to keep their dependencies up to date.**

See more at "[**Configuring automated security fixes**](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-automated-security-fixes)"

> Note: Automatic security fixes are available in beta and are subject to change.
>
> You can enable automatic security fixes for any repository that uses security alerts and the dependency graph.
> We'll automatically enable automatic security fixes in every repository that uses security alerts and the dependency graph over the next few months, starting in May 2019.

Comment: I've had mixed results with that bot. I prefer manually doing `npm audit` and/or `npm audit fix`.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator OK. You mentioned https://medium.com/coinmonks/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8 in a previous comment?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.
uninstall all of your dependencies and install it again

**For example**

from **package.json** see list of your dependencies

```
{
"name": "ebook-saler",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "App for selling ebooks",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "Md Shayon",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.1.0",
    "hoek": "^6.1.3",
    "stripe": "^7.5.0"
  }
}
```

Follow the command for this

```
npm uninstall body-parser express express-handlebars hoek stripe
npm install body-parser express express-handlebars hoek stripe
git commit -m "updated"
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

try `npm audit fix`, it will solve many warnings

then `npm i [package.name]@xxx`

for example:

```
"dependencies": {
  "lodash": ">=4.17.13"
}
```

`npm i lodash@4.17.13`

Answer (score 0):

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. Under your repository name, click  Security.
3. Click the alert you'd like to view.
4. Review the details of the vulnerability and, if available, the pull request containing the automated security fix.
5. Optionally, if there isn't already an automated security fix for the alert, to create a pull request to resolve the vulnerability, click Create automated security fix.
6. When you're ready to update your dependency and resolve the vulnerability, merge the pull request.

[See details](https://help.github.com/en/articles/viewing-and-updating-vulnerable-dependencies-in-your-repository)