# Github potential security vulnerability error for hoek node module

Tags: git, github, node-modules, package.json, package-lock.json

Today github is showing following error on my github repository:

> We found a potential security vulnerability in one of your
>   dependencies. A dependency defined in ./package-lock.json has known
>   security vulnerabilities and should be updated.

On clicking on Review vulnerable dependency button following message was displayed:

> hoek node module before 5.0.3 suffers from a Modification of
>   Assumed-Immutable Data (MAID) vulnerability via 'merge'

Till yesterday it was not showing such error. I have not done any push to this repository for more than 5 days. Any idea why it is happening.

Comment: It's very much possible that a security vulnerability in hoek was only discovered recently. It's clearly happening because a) your project uses hoek, b) certain versions of hoek have a security vulnerability, and c) Github now considers this vulnerability sufficiently important to warn you. The fact that you haven't pushed for days is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`npm update` should work only **if the vulnerable package is declared as direct project's dependency**. But usually (as in the case of `hoek`) **vulnerabilities lay** in those packages which live **down in you sub-dependencies tree**.

Since in my case **I decided to not update all the dependencies of my project** (by deleting and rebuilding the entire `package-lock.json` file), I went for the following (and, of course, more time consuming) approach:

- **find** all the **occurrencies** of the vulnerable package in my `package-lock.json`
- **follow up** the dependency tree to find which **top-level packages** import them
- **uninstall** and **re-install** those **top-level packages** using the same minor version

Like:

```
npm r package-1 package-2 && npm i package-1@^1.2.3 package-2@^1.2.3
```

This approach will work only if the vulnerable package was fixed and released and the consuming packages import the vulnerable one with a [loose version number open to patch or minor versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: `node-sass` for example willingly imports the old `hoek` version to maintain backwards compatibility :( https://github.com/sass/node-sass/pull/2170

Answer (score 8):

I used: `rm package-lock.json` && `npm update && npm install`. For me this updated `hoek` to `4.2.1`, which also contains the fix ([per this comment](https://github.com/request/request/issues/2926#issuecomment-384853637).)

**Edit:** In another app, I ran `rm package-lock.json` and either `npm i hoek && npm up && npm i && npm un hoek` or `npm i hoek && npm un hoek && npm up && npm i` (can't recall order), which is more aligned [with this comment (from JamesSingleton)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48783#issuecomment-384873041).

(`rm package-lock.json` is only if it exists.)

**Edit:** In yet a 3rd app, I checked `npm outdated` and found I had to upgrade `react-scripts-ts` from `2.13.0` to `2.15.1`. For this, I updated the `package.json` manually, then just ran `npm i`. Once done, `hoek` updated to `4.2.1.` (specifically targeting that one holdout/primary component).

**Edit:** My solution for a Zurb Foundation 6 Site:

I updated all my packages to their major versions using `npm outdated`. I then ran:

`npm i hoek@latest --save && npm up hoek`

`npm i boom hawk sntp uncss gulp-uncss --save && npm up boom hawk sntp uncss gulp-uncss && npm un boom hawk sntp gulp-uncss uncss --save`

There were two holdouts; `browser-sync : 2.23.7` and `node-sass : 4.9.0`, both at their latest versions. No matter: the GitHub warning resolved after commit.

Comment: I tried all the solutions mentioned by you  but unfortunately none of them worked for me.

Comment: Most of my apps also did not have `hoek` as a direct dependency, but installing it as one propagated the newer version down through the sub-packages. @YuvrajPatil In your `package-lock.json`, what sub-packages show as still dependent on the older `2.16.3`?

Comment: `npm i hoek@latest --save && npm up hoek` worked for me. thank you keith

Answer (score 5):

I used npm update hoek && npm install hoek and the package was updated to 5.0.3.

The vulnerability alert disappeared from my github Repo after that.

Comment: On my 3rd app, in addition to upgrading my component, I also had to `npm i hoek && npm up` as well. These dependency warnings are certainly teaching me more about `npm`.

Comment: In my case hoek is not direct dependency hence it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above worked for me. My hoek dependency was deep in the subtrees. I first did `npm ls hoek` and got something like this:

```
├── hoek@5.0.3
└─┬ watson-developer-cloud@2.42.0
  ├─┬ request@2.83.0
  │ └─┬ hawk@6.0.2
  │   ├─┬ boom@4.3.1
  │   │ └── hoek@4.2.1  deduped
  │   ├─┬ cryptiles@3.1.2
  │   │ └─┬ boom@5.2.0
  │   │   └── hoek@4.2.1  deduped
  │   ├── hoek@4.2.1
  │   └─┬ sntp@2.1.0
  │     └── hoek@4.2.1  deduped
  └─┬ solr-client@0.7.0
    └─┬ request@2.81.0
      └─┬ hawk@3.1.3
        ├─┬ boom@2.10.1
        │ └── hoek@2.16.3  deduped
        ├── hoek@2.16.3
        └─┬ sntp@1.0.9
          └── hoek@2.16.3  deduped
```

I then saw that what really needs to be updated is `watson-developer-cloud` since that is what using hoek at the top level.

I then did `npm install watson-developer-cloud@latest` and that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try run `npm install hoek@4.2.x` or `npm install hoek@5` in your project.

That will install the required latest version of hoek into package.json dependencies overwriting above hoek version in package-lock.json.

Comment: In my case hoek is not direct dependency hence it did not work.

Comment: Can you please provide some more inputs about your code to help understand your case better.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48783).

Basically in git bash, `cd` to your project folder, type the following codes:

```
npm i hoek  
npm uninstall hoek 
npm update 
npm install
```

then

```
git add .
git commit -m 'update-hoek'
git push origin master
```

Now check your GitHub project page again, the warning should disappear.

Regards.

Comment: In my case hoek is not direct dependency hence it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above, but non worked for me, so I went ahead to check the root cause of mine.

I ran `npm ls hoek` which gave me:

```
├─┬ fuse-box@3.3.0
│ └─┬ request@2.81.0
│   └─┬ hawk@3.1.3
│     ├─┬ boom@2.10.1
│     │ └── hoek@2.16.3
│     ├── hoek@2.16.3
│     └─┬ sntp@1.0.9
│       └── hoek@2.16.3
└── hoek@5.0.3
```

I noticed the version of my `hawk` against the one on [npm hawk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hawk), so I ran `npm i hawk --save`. After which I again ran my normal git commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'whatever_message'
git push
```

And went back to Github and my **security vulnerability** was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the package CVE-2018-3728 is vulnerable. The versions of hoek prior to 4.2.1 and 5.0.3 are vulnerable to prototype pollution.
The affected versions of hoek are until version 5.0.2,  The remediation is to update to version 4.2.1, 5.0.3 or later.
For more information, you can view the fix pull request here: https://github.com/hapijs/hoek/pull/231/commits/5aed1a8c4a3d55722d1c799f2368857bf418d6df