# Override npm package dependency

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, package.json

I read this: [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)

Unfortunately, it does not solve my problem.

I am trying to change a package from using a specific dependency to use another version of that dependency.

Is it built into a package what version of a dependency it should use, or is it possible to change it?

In my case specifically, I am trying to change `css-loader`'s default dependency on `cssnano@3.10.0` (*latest*) to instead be dependent on `cssnano@4.0.0-rc.2` (*next*).

From the second answer in the above link, user *trickpatty* notes that:

> this will be removed anytime you run npm i instead of editing your
>   package-lock.json and adding the child dependency to "dependencies"
>   there, add the child dependency to your package.json "dependencies"
>   section

Including `cssnano@4.0.0-rc.2` in package.json's devDependencies does nothing to `css-loader`. It still uses the other (default) version of `cssnano`.

Comment: _"Is it built into a package what version of a dependency it should use"_ <- yes. _"is it possible to change it"_ <- also yes

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? Works for me if I run `npm i --save css-loader && npm i --save-dev cssnano@4.0.0-rc.2`. Run `tail node_modules/cssnano/package.json` to confirm. Mine has `"version": "4.0.0-rc.2"`

Comment: Thanks @Phil , I think they updated the packages. This was a problem when css-loader used a broken version of cssnano. Thus inspiring me to find out if I could somehow force it to use another version.

Comment: The version of `cssnano` that `css-loader@0.28.11` depends on is still `3.10.0`. I'll ask again; what makes you think it's not working?

Comment: @Phil If you run `npm list cssnano` you will see that there are two versions of cssnano installed, but that css-loader indeed still is dependent on the lower version (it shows as a "subfolder")

Comment: `npm list` shows the dependencies of the package but they won't necessarily won't be what's installed. Given NPM's flat directory structure, you can only have one copy of a library installed.

Comment: @Phil Ah, ok, so we can be absolutely certain that even though `npm list` shows a structure like that, it actually uses the version that's installed? I wonder how the developers would protect against this. I mean, do they just openly allow their module to use any version of a dependency (whichever is installed), or is it just versions "higher than X" or similar...

Comment: @Phil "Given NPM's flat directory structure" - um, NPM famously has a highly nested directory structure, with multiple versions of every package able to be installed. Are you thinking of something else?

Comment: @Magnus Phil is completely wrong. Each package uses its nested dependencies first

Comment: @Phil I used it in 2018 and 2017 and 2011. The module system has always worked like that.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica I'm just going by what I thought I saw at the time. I could have sworn everything was at the top level of `node_modules`. I'm also quite happy to be wrong here. Glad I didn't provide an answer then :). _Edit:_ pretty sure this is what I was seeing ~ https://npm.github.io/how-npm-works-docs/npm3/how-npm3-works.html, obviously I got confused

Answer (score 2):

NPM 8 introduced "overrides" which allows you to override specific transitive dependencies of your direct dependency. For your usecase, you would declare something like below in your package.json.

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "css-loader": {
      "cssnano": "4.0.0-rc.2"
    }
  }
}
```

More details @ https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Comment: Can I somehow choose a different package to resolve to?

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives:

- If you can use different package manager, yarn has an option to achieve it by adding to the `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
    "package-a": "2.0.0"
}
```

- If you can use latest Node LTS and NPM 8: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides
- Otherwise, you can use some tool like https://github.com/mislavlukach/flatten-dependencies that runs on postinstall script to fix your problem of different nested dependencies versions. You will need to install that version as dependency in your project.

EDIT: Found another alternative: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions

Comment: Thank you; this is actually the most thorough answer that covers several alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The following in your `package.json` can help you here. How it works is that it overrides all the versions of `cssnano` that `css-loader` requests with the version you've specified instead.

[**See the docs**](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides)

```js
"overrides": {
  "css-loader": {
     "cssnano": "1.2.3"
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In *package.json* you can add `resolutions` and give the path of dependency which was used. This is example from my project:

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "helmet/helmet-csp": "2.9.1",
    "jest/**/handlebars": "4.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a feature of yarn, not npm

Comment: If you want to use `resolutions` in NPM, you need to use it in conjunction with _npm-force-resolutions_ (https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions). This is useful for supporting users below npm 8.3, which is when `overrides` was introduced into NPM itself.  However, it should be noted the nested/wildcard notation will +NOT+ work with _npm-force-resolutions_ but only with `yarn`, as the first comment here correctly states.

Answer (score -4):

This thread is a bit old and maybe already resolved, but maybe there is someone with the same question.

In my opinion, you should not change the dependency versions of your dependencies. Each project is developed, tested, and published considering their declared dependency versions. You could break or change the behavior of a package changing its dependencies externally.

Instead, think in making a fork of the project (css-loader), change the dependency version, test by yourself, and do use your fork. You can also open a pull request to the project maintainer (if you think the change will benefit the community) or publish your version (respecting the licensing policy).

Comment: This is done for security purposes mostly or else the entire application will in be in jeopardy we don't change just because we love to :)