# NPM: How can update a module which is a dependency of another module

Tags: npm, lodash, npm-install, jshint

I need to update lodash to a 4.17.5 or later version. This module is a dependency of jshint module like you can see in the next pic:

[image]

How can I update lodash from 3.7.0 version to 4.17.5 or later version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)