# Installing specific version of dependencies for a package inside that package in package.json

Tags: javascript, package.json

I know the title is confusing but I wasn't sure how to word my issue...

I am using a package in my App called "react-dnd-html5-backend".  This specific package has a dependency called "autobind-decorator".  autobind-decorator recently posted an update to their package that introduced conflicts in a few spots in my App. I would like to specify that "react-dnd-html5-backend" use the exact version that I know is compatible wit my code.  Is there a way to specify that in my package.json file?  To specify the version of "autobind-decorator" that "react-dnd-html5-backend" uses while in my application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `autobind-decorator` with a specific version as a dependency into your project's `package.json` will force to install that version.

Note that `react-dnd-html5-backend` should support to use `autobind-decorator` version, if not it will cause a version conflict error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gonzalo!  I believe I tried that but was unable to override the version used by "react-dnd-html5-backend"
In my impatience I actually found a different solution that I figured I should post in case anyone else runs into the same problem.  It looks like you can specify the version of a nested package by using the resolutions field of the package.json:

https://github.com/yarnpkg/rfcs/pull/68/files

```
Example:
"resolutions": {
    "**/autobind-decorator": "2.1.0"
  }
```