# npm - getting rid of nested node_modules in one specific module

Tags: npm

I'm kind of lost here!

I'm using a module which has another module nested in its' node_modules.
I.E.

```
my_project
    node_modules
        widely_used_module
        parent_dependency
            node_modules
               widely_used_module
```

I have some fixes in my "own" widely_used_module (it could be just a minor version from the original distributor, but to be completely honest, in this case its' my fork on Github containing some critical fixes).

When I manually remove `node_modules/parent_dependency/node_modules`, parent_dependency starts to reference to my "widely used module" instead of its' own. But this of course gets overriden once I hit npm install again.

1. Can I somehow prevent a package to install its' own modules, or can I force a package to reference the root node_modules and ignore its' own?
2. Is that even the right approach to fixing such issues? I don't want to fork parent_dependency as well...

Thank you

Comment: is it helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions

Comment: @HardikModha maybe I should read more about it, but it seems that when I remove the descendant dependencies from either  `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json` they are being retrieved as soon as I `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question;
[Yarn has a built-in solution](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) for this **exact** issue.
This could be achievable with NPM as well but yarn made it so easy to fix that I moved the project dependencies to be handled by yarn.

Full solution:

1. [Installing yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable)
2. Ran `yarn` in project's root path
3. Removed `package.lock.json`
4. Added `resolutions` to my package.json. In my case:

   `{
       "dependencies": {
           "...": "...",
           "parent_dependency": "^x.y.z"
       },
       "devDependencies": {
           "...": "..."
       },
       "resolutions": {
           "parent_dependency/widely_used_module": "git+https://git@github.com/myuser/widely_used_module.git"
       }
   }`
5. Ran `yarn install`.

Result: No more `widely_used_module` folder under `parent_dependency`.