# how do I ensure all package.json dependencies go to the same version

Tags: npm, package.json

I have a problem with `path-to-regexp`, I want to ensure if possible all dependencies go through 3.0.0.

I have ran

`npm i path-to-regexp` it adds this to my package.json:

```
"path-to-regexp": "^3.0.0",
```

But when I run

`npm ls path-to-regexp`

I get:

```
├── path-to-regexp@3.0.0
├─┬ react-router-dom@5.0.0
│ └─┬ react-router@5.0.0
│   └── path-to-regexp@1.7.0
└─┬ react-scripts@3.0.1
  └─┬ webpack-dev-server@3.2.1
    └─┬ express@4.17.0
      └── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
```

I want `react-router-dom` use 3.0.0.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)

Answer (score 0):

Different modules are released by different teams, on different schedules, with independent version numbers. It makes no sense to force "all dependencies" to the same version.

How to override a specific dependency version, in your case `react-router-dom`, is explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17423915/11451509