# NPM how to update/upgrade transitive dependencies?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am using express v4.16.4 in my node server.

It has pulled in cookie-signature v1.0.6.

I want to upgrade cookie-signature to v1.1.0 as it has a fix which I require.
What is the way to do that ?

I don't think i should do a npm install cookie-signature@1.1.0 as it would list cookie-signature in my app dependencies.

EDIT: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions) discusses the exact same problem that i am looking to solve. The accepted answer is using npm-shrinkwrap, and another top voted answer using package-lock.json , but both of these seem to have issues as discussed in respective comments.

Happy to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)

Answer (score 22):

You might also be able to solve the issue by adding a `resolutions` key in the `package.json` to "enforce" certain versions of dependencies:

```json
{
  "resolutions": {
    "cookie-signature": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

To actually make use of that, you have to use `npm-force-resolutions` in `preinstall`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
}
```

See this post for further information: https://itnext.io/fixing-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-dependencies-in-less-than-3-mins-a53af735261d

Comment: Awesome.  I'm so glad npm figured out a manageable solution to this.

Comment: NPM 8 has native support for this, please check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490790/1043288

Answer (score 17):

NPM 8 introduced "overrides" which allows you to override specific transitive dependencies of your direct dependency. For your usecase, you would declare something like below in your package.json.

```
{
  "overrides": {
    "express": {
      "cookie-signature": "1.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

More details @ https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Answer (score 2):

We had a very similar problem. Protractor 5.4.2 has a dependency on webdriver-manager@^12.0.6. In package-lock.json webdriver-manager was fixed to 12.1.5. However, we needed 12.1.7 in order to make it work with all the latest chrome versions.

We noticed, that npm would install version 12.1.7 when removing node_modules and package-lock.json, but we did not find a way to automatically update package-lock.json. So these are the steps we took:

1. Remove node_modules
2. Remove package-lock.json
3. Run `npm install`
4. Open package-lock.json and copy the webdriver-manager section to another file
5. Undo (git checkout) all changes in package-lock.json
6. Copy the saved webdriver-manager part back into package-lock.json
7. Remove node_modules
8. Run `npm install`
9. Check node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/package.json that the right version was installed.

I think this workaround should work for express and cookies-signature as well.

Comment: Where in these steps are you changing the transitive dependency version?

Comment: @montrealist step 3 writes the new version (of possibly other modules too) to `package-lock.json`, in step 6 you manually change it, from the backup created in step 4. However, I think you could skip steps 4 to 8 if you only remove `webdriver-manager` (and its dependencies, if you also require new versions there) from `node_modules` in step 1. In step 3 npm should then only write new versions for the _removed_ dependencies to the newly generated package-lock.json (check your unstaged changes). At least it worked like this in my case.