# How to update tar as a peer dependency to avoid buffer over-read vulnerability?

Tags: reactjs, npm, tar

My React application has certain dependencies which have tar package as their peer dependency. The AquaSec/Security Scan reports `tar@6.1.11` to have a **buffer over-read vulnerability** (CVE-2020-8244). The suggested version is said to be `tar@6.1.12`.

How can I update the tar package to avoid issue related to vulnerability?

This is what I see when I do a `npm list tar` in my app.

```
+-- copy-webpack-plugin@6.4.1
| `-- cacache@15.3.0
|   `-- tar@6.1.11
`-- node-sass@8.0.0
  +-- make-fetch-happen@10.2.1
  | `-- cacache@16.1.3
  |   `-- tar@6.1.11  deduped
  `-- node-gyp@8.4.1
    `-- tar@6.1.11  deduped
```

Also, my `package.json` don't have tar in the list of dependencies cause it is used as a peer dependency.

Comment: Transitive dependencies is the term for this, not peer dependencies, in this case. See the answer on Overrides here: [NPM how to update/upgrade transitive dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634474/npm-how-to-update-upgrade-transitive-dependencies)