# How to use Vuejs with template compiler with Webpack

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, package.json

I'm using Webpack.

I loosely followed this tutorial to configure Vuejs into my build: https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-configure-webpack-4-with-vuejs-a-complete-guide-209e943c4772

I was able to get it to work, but when I tried to render a template, I got an error (in the browser): "You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available.".

The actual Vuejs installation under `node_modules` has several variations, including the full package with the compiler, which is what I want.

However, Webpack decides to include the runtime version.

I dag some more, and found that if I modify `node_modules/vue/package.json`, and change its `main` key from `dist/vue.runtime.common.js` to `dist/vue.common.js` and its `module` key from `dist/vue.runtime.esm.js` to `dist/vue.esm.js` - Webpack DOES pick the full version.

I am looking for a way to get this effect without changing Vue's own package.json.
I found this: [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions) , and tried the accepted answer, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Can anyone tell me the "right way" to achieve my goal, i.e. to have Webpack include the full version of Vuejs, instead of just the runtime?

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds

Comment: @EricDay thanks, it worked! If you post it as an answer I will accept it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is contained in Vue's installation:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds

> In the dist/ directory of the NPM package you will find many different builds of Vue.j...
>
> Runtime: code that is responsible for creating Vue instances, rendering and patching virtual DOM, etc. Basically everything minus the compiler...
>
> Runtime + Compiler vs. Runtime-only
> If you need to compile templates on the client (e.g. passing a string to the template option, or mounting to an element using its in-DOM HTML as the template), you will need the compiler and thus the full build

Comment: The answer I'm looking for is how to pre-compile the functions during build step rather than loading a larger library at run-time.