# Angular and NPM dependencies VS devDependencies

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

after un bunch of reading on this matter and following this very usefull post : [What's the difference between dependencies, devDependencies and peerDependencies in npm package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies/)

I know that dependencies should reference every runtime libs and devDependencies references every usefull for development dependencies.

But I am now confused. For production usage, I will have to `ng build --production` my Angular app. If I do `npm install --production`, I can't even compile with `ng build --production`. I **need** to `npm install` and get every devDependencies installed. Knowing that, I tried to put everything under devDependencies, And then I did a `ng build --prod`, the resulting **[dist]** folder has everything needed, and can be served as a full angular app.

**So, 1st question is : Appart from make an "on paper" difference between runtime libs and dev libs, why should I use dependencies ?**

Other question: To avoid vulnerabilities on dependencies of dependencies I can force the usage of a specific version by putting this lib in the package.json (as long as the major version is the same). But I would like to avoid putting this lib in the dependencies or devDependencies, should I put this lib under peerDependencies ? optionnalDependencies ? bundledDependencies ?

Thanks for any inputs on this.

**EDIT**

Example package.json has been required:

```
{
  "name": "ANGULAR_PROJECT",
  "version": "X.Y.Z",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "A_GIT_URL"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "test": "ng test",
    "e2e": "protractor e2e/conf/protractor.conf.js",
    "e2e:dev": "protractor e2e/conf/protractor-dev.conf.js",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.11",
    "@mat-datetimepicker/core": "^2.0.1",
    "@mat-datetimepicker/moment": "^2.0.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "8.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "8.4.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "8.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "8.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "8.4.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "12.0.1",
    "angular-gridster2": "^8.2.0",
    "angular-particle": "^1.0.4",
    "array-flat-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "apollo-angular": "^1.8.0",
    "apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.9.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.3",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.4",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.13",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "graphql": "14.0.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "json-server": "^0.14.2",
    "jsonpath": "^1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-cacheable": "^1.2.5",
    "ngx-parallax": "^4.0.0",
    "node-sass": "4.13.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2-pr208",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1",
    ----------------------------------------------- REAL DEV DEPENDENCIES UNDER
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.11",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.6",
    "@types/cucumber": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "~5.2.0",
    "commitizen": "^4.0.3",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "cucumber": "5.1.0",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.0.2",
    "cz-customizable": "^5.3.0",
    "cz-customizable-ghooks": "^1.5.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-sonarqube-reporter": "^1.2.5",
    "karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter": "^0.0.21",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "ng-mocks": "^8.1.0",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "protractor": "5.4.2",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-comparators": "^1.0.0",
    "ts-mockery": "1.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {

  }
}
```

Comment: We cannot evaluate your problem without seeing your package.json here. Seems like you have dependencies falsely allocated under devDependencies.

Comment: I am talking about principle here but I can had an example package.json, that will build properly for prod environment, with everything under devDependencies.

Comment: During build process with `ng build --prod`  you compile your project with all its required packages during "development process". Then you have your static files compiled with no more need to package.. But I think this will not work for server side rendering for example.. I'm waiting too for the community answers

Comment: Well I can answer : this is working: I actually have an express node.js app serving this [dist] inside the project, because the [dist] folder is all compiled with everything needed. I only put express & node.js lib under dependencies to reduce my node_modules size. This is a real prod case usage. I know this is not ideal and we will remove express / node to actually use a real web server. But **again** I am talking about principles :D

Comment: Well this is not an inspiring question apparently :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Appart from make an "on paper" difference between runtime libs and dev libs, why should I use dependencies ?**

Response : It makes no difference do what you want. But know this:

- It's good to know if a dependency is a prod or dev dependency, even if it's an "on paper" difference so try to be accurate.
- To know for sure if a dependency is really used in your final build, you can use special lib for that. I got a preference for https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer, because it enables to search a dependency through a search field
- If you need to use some npm command with --prod, These will just use the "dependencies" stack in your package.json. npm ls @angular-devkit/build-angular --json --prod won't return any result if this dependency is in the "devDependencies". But it will return a result if @angular-devkit/build-angular is in "dependencies"

And for the other question :
**To avoid vulnerabilities on dependencies of dependencies I can force the usage of a specific version by putting this lib in the package.json (as long as the major version is the same). But I would like to avoid putting this lib in the dependencies or devDependencies, should I put this lib under peerDependencies ? optionnalDependencies ? bundledDependencies ?**

Response : the best way to do that is to use the npm tool : **npm-force-resolutions** and not to reference these dependencies under any of these entries

more info on npm-force-resolutions : here for example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62956076/2376892