# How can I enforce the version on a dependency of a used library

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm using package `foo` that has `"bar": "^1.0.0"` in it's dependencies.

I want to force my package `foo` to use the fixed version`"bar": "1.0.0"`, because the latest patched version of `bar` is broken.

Is there a way to do this ?

Or do I have no choice but to fork `foo` library with `"bar": "1.0.0"` specified.

Comment: May this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions I do not mark it as duplicated, because I don't know if forcing version is only for you (local) or in case you're developping `foo` with other underlying dependencies that require `bar`

Answer (score 0):

[npm force resolution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions) can do the trick...

install npm force resulution

```sh
npm install --save-dev npm-force-resolutions
```

modify `package.json`

```sh
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
},
"resolutions": {
  "bar": "1.0.0"
}
```

then run `npm install`