# Can you force npm sub-dependency to install from a GitHub pull request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, geofirestore

I am installing `geofirestore` which requires `geofirestore-core`.

`geofirestore-core` [has a bug](https://github.com/MichaelSolati/geofirestore-core/issues/3) that's [fixed in a pull request](https://github.com/MichaelSolati/geofirestore-core/pull/2) which hasn't been merged. How can I force my installed version of `geofirestore` to use the version of `geofirestore-core` in the pull request instead of the one registered in NPM?

Following the answer here, [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions), I took the steps below to use [shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-shrinkwrap):

1. Ran `npm shrinkwrap`
2. Updated the `geofirestore-core` to point to `MarcARoberge/geofirestore-core#feat-firebase8`
3. Ran `npm install` again;

Unfortunately, this just overwrote my updated version in shrinkwrap what I am doing wrong?

```
// npm-shrinkwrap.json
"geofirestore": {
  "version": "4.3.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/geofirestore/-/geofirestore-4.3.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-NFaOm6BSwAGU+HuYR11St5LgJ67LRYUeeKiF7iPs5/gJgHrpnbFxqe2t3jAW13jpAeoLHnxEoQsPyt94JpZCAw==",
  "requires": {
     // user/repo#branch point to pull request 
     "geofirestore-core": "MarcARoberge/geofirestore-core#feat-firebase8"
   }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up cloning the dependency, updating its package.json to point to the fixed repo and pointing my local dependency to the cloned version on GitHub.