# Fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependencies, mapbox

I am trying to npm install vue-mapbox mapbox-gl, and I'm getting a dependency tree error.

I'm running [Nuxt.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxt.js) SSR with Vuetify and haven't installed anything related to Mapbox prior to running this install and am getting this error.

```
38 error code ERESOLVE
39 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
40 error
41 error While resolving: "example"@"1.0.0"
41 error Found: mapbox-gl@"1.13.0"
41 error node_modules/mapbox-gl
41 error   mapbox-gl@"^1.13.0" from the root project
41 error
41 error Could not resolve dependency:
41 error peer mapbox-gl@"^0.53.0" from vue-mapbox@"0.4.1"
41 error node_modules/vue-mapbox
41 error   vue-mapbox@"*" from the root project
41 error
41 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
41 error this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
41 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
41 error
41 error See /Users/user/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
42 verbose exit 1
```

What's the right way to go about fixing this upstream dependency conflict?

Comment: A few years ago I switched to `yarn` because of this. Today I went with `npm` and couldn't believe this is still happening. I know npm tries to be explicit and isn't doing anything wrong, but how are beginner developers supposed to get around this hurdle at the start of their career? It's unfortunate to tell new developers at the very beginning to install another package manager. And yes, one could simply do one of the suggestions, but it does not raise any confidence in a beginner's mind (even though I guess yarn is just doing the same per default). Anyway, just wanted to leave my 2 cents.

Comment: @RobinWieruch same, I switched all my builds over to Yarn and haven't had any problems since

Answer (score 292, accepted):

It looks like it's a problem with *peer dependencies* in the latest version of npm (v7) which is still a beta version.

Try with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. For detailed information check the blog post *[npm v7 Series - Beta Release! And: SemVer-Major Changes in npm v7](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major)*.

Comment: What is that flag?

Comment: [npm: When to use `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps) might be helpful

Comment: Actually, this is not the right answer. You are forcing a version without understanding the cause and the conflict, this warning wasnt added without a reason. It might generate security leaks and unexpected bugs. A better option would be understand the conflict, fix it, or pin the version to be used. I've detailed in an answer below.

Comment: `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true` solves the problem

Comment: If NPM is not able to do this automatically, then what is the purpose of it

Comment: @JatinVarlyani thanks "npm config set legacy-peer-deps true" is worked for me

Answer (score 129):

### Problem explanation:

Your dependency `mexample` requires `mmapbox-gl` v1.13.0 and `mvue-mapbox` requires `mmapbox-gl` v0.53.0.

NPM doesn't know which version to install, so it gives a warning. You can bypass the errors using `-- force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`, but you are ignoring an error, and making unexpected results.

### Fix the error (Production best practices):

1. Probably one of your packages is outdated. Upgrading packages and fixing upgrade errors might fix the dependency conflict.
2. Overriding a dependency manually to avoid the warning and error. You are setting the version to a specific one that you know that works. Usually the newer version.

Example solution with override. Your *package.json* file will look like this:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "mexample": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-mapbox": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "mmapbox-gl": "1.13.0"
  }
}
```

### Bypass the error (quick and dirty solution):

1. `--legacy-peer-deps` completely ignores all *peerDependencies* using the newest version without pinning on file *package-lock.json*
2. `--force` forces the use of the newest, pinning all the versions on *package-lock.json*

Extra: You shouldn't use "*" as a version, because it might update major and break dependencies.

Comment: this is a way better answer than most others here. If I could give extra points, I would !

Comment: Literally the only intelligent answer to this question. A thorough explanation of the causes of the problem, followed by viable solutions and the rationale behind each.  Well done sir. Well done.

Answer (score 51):

Use `--legacy-peer-deps` after `npm install`. For example, if you want to install [Radium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/radium#how-does-radium-work), use:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save radium
```

Answer (score 36):

There are *two* ways:

1. use `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` to install, and if this doesn't work use
2. the force method. Add --force next to *npm install*: `npm install --force`

Answer (score 35):

You can follow these commands

First type:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

Then type:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Please explain your commands too :(

Comment: this worked thanks

Answer (score 25):

I tried multiple ways, but nothing was working for me. At last I tried this and it worked:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

Run this in the project folder and then try to install any package. It might work for you as well.

Comment: This worked for me as well but I have no idea what the command even means lol.

Comment: setting ```npm config set legacy-peer-deps true``` before ```npm install``` worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

Until npm version 7.19.1, it still had the same issue. After upgrading to version 7.20.3, use command `npm install -g npm@latest` and `npm audit fix`. All packages will be fixed without error.

Comment: For me this answer worked the best (Node v16.14.0, npm v8.3.1, Angular 13.2.4).
But I had to run it with the `--force` flag, like this `npm audit fix --force`. Thanks!

Comment: Actually when trying to build the project, this solution caused other build errors related to `ng2-logger` (`tnp-core/browser`, more exactly).
So I had to fallback to `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` which actually made build work.

Answer (score 7):

I was stuck on this issue for long which also makes error from other commands which calls for some install commands that was breaking.

The only solution that works (maybe suppresses the error) is

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

This will set the configuration of `legacy-peer-deps` to `true`

Answer (score 6):

To resolve npm dependencies and conflicts with npm packages, use [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).

Comment: IDK if this is what the OP was asking, but it was certainly what I was thinking when I Googled: okay, so there are conflicts. How do I resolve them rather than work around them with a command line switch?

Answer (score 4):

To solve it, fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM packages error

Method 1. Just use `--legacy-peer-deps` after `npm install`.

For example, if you want to install [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), use

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps --save axios.
```

Method 2. Updating npm and 'audit fix'

```
npm I -g npm@latest
npm audit fix --force
```

Method 3. Using `--force` to install packages

```
npm install axios --force
```

Answer (score 4):

Almost all answers here suggest using `force` or `legacy-peer-deps`. Though this will technically work, please note that this is not recommended by NPM if you can avoid it anymore ([source](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/v7.24.2/CHANGELOG.md#dependency-resolution)). Some folks may not have a choice, but I was able to resolve my dependency conflicts by deleting `node-modules` and `package-lock.json` then manually updating packages to their latest version one at a time until it stopped complaining (packages mentioned in the error messages after running `npm i`. Not a great or clean solution, but at least my packages are up-to-date and I'm not ignoring errors or using legacy solutions.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of upvotes for using `--legacy-peer-deps`, but if `--force` works, I would recommend using that since it still pins many dependency versions while `--legacy-peer-deps` ignores peer dependencies entirely. See the example below:

*[npm: When to use `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66608842/3850405)*

I started getting this error on [Azure DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server) a few days ago. I initially thought it was a glitch on the Azure side, but since it continued, we started looking into it a bit more.

It turns out the agent we are using, `windows-2022`, was updated a few days ago:

*[Updating readme file for win22 version 20220607.3 (#5713)](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/commit/2950cbfeab88a6a6202fa31d7371e574dbe2dc51)*

Node and NPM now match the *latest* Node.js LTS version: 16.15.1 (includes npm 8.11.0)

*[Downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)*

You can view all agents-included software on *[Microsoft-hosted agents, Software](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software)*.

After reading on Microsoft Visual Studio Developer Community, they recommend downgrading Node.js using *Node.js Tool Installer task* like this:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.14.2'
```

*[Node.js Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js?view=azure-devops)*

*[npm install fails in Azure DevOps Hosted Agent](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/npm-install-fails-in-azure-devops-hosted-agent/1606509)*

However, we decided that we do not want to downgrade Node.js, so the first step was matching Node.js locally with LTS version 16.15.1 and npm 8.11.0.

When running `npm ci`, we then got the same error locally.

We tried `npm ci --force` and we then got this error:

> `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and
> package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update
> your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.

`npm install` gave the same error even after `node_modules` was manually removed, but `npm install --force` worked, and it generated a new *package-lock.json* file.

`npm ci` still failed with the same error, but running `npm ci --force` worked. We decided to update Azure DevOps `.yml` to include `--force` and checked in the new *package-lock.json* file. After doing this, everything worked like before and we could now update our packages one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing here worked for me.

After struggling with this issue for so long, I found a solution that worked.
Apparently I had some packages installed globally.

Listed them with:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Then removed the unwanted packages with:

```
npm uninstall -g <package-name>
```

Finally I got the problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

- delete the *package-lock.json* file
- modify the *package.json* file, updating the version as indicated by the peer dependency

Add a tilde or caret for allowing install latest version and resolving dependency issues, for example :

~1.0.2 means to install version 1.0.2 or the latest patch version such as 1.0.4.

^1.0.2 means to install version 1.0.2 or the latest minor or patch version such as 1.1.0.

- run npm install or npm udpate

Comment: But modify it how? It seems like circular dependencies that can't be resolved as one package needs that version while the other needs the current version etc.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
```

Comment: Does the code snippet work?

Comment: Yes it works! it's a command that will specifies the version of npm your app is using.

Comment: To what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

npm install **What you want to install** --legacy-peer-deps

Example- I replace here @reach/router = What you want to install