# npm: When to use `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-ci

I'm trying to understand how recreating the `node_modules` directory for deployment works.

We're using `npm ci` instead of `npm install` to ensure a clean slate during deployment. However, when we run it without any flags, we get the following error:

> Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

The ***[documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install)*** for `npm install` for `--force` is as follows (there are no flags on `npm ci`'s ***[page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci)***):

> The -f or --force argument will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.

Meanwhile, the documentation for `--legacy-peer-deps` says:

> --legacy-peer-deps: ignore all peerDependencies when installing, in the style of npm version 4 through version 6.

It seems that both flags will let `npm ci` generate the `node_modules` directory without any issues, but I am still unclear about the differences between the two.

From what I understand, `--force` sounds like it will be on a last-dependency-downloaded-wins basis and will overwrite any previously downloaded dependencies. Meanwhile, `--legacy-peer-deps` sounds like it will always skip peer dependencies (whatever those are) during installation even if there are no issues.

What are the differences between the two flags, and when should we use them?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

In the new version of npm (v7), by default, `npm install` will fail when it encounters conflicting *peerDependencies*. It was not like that before.

Take a look [here](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#peer-dependencies) for more info about peer dependencies in npm v7.

The differences between the two are below -

- `--legacy-peer-deps`: ignore all *peerDependencies* when installing, in the style of npm version 4 through version 6.
- `--strict-peer-deps`: fail and abort the install process for any conflicting *peerDependencies* when encountered. By default, npm will only crash for *peerDependencies* conflicts caused by the direct dependencies of the root project.
- `--force`: will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.

Comment: and what of `--force` per OP? Are there performance benefits with one over the other or overall deduped packages, etc?

Comment: `--force` still pins many dependency versions while `--legacy-peer-deps`  ignore peer dependencies entirely. See example from @HongboMiao

Comment: The question is about the when to use what but I don't see that in the answer. Can you elaborate more about what are the differences between the 2?

Answer (score 89):

In the article *[npm 7 is now generally available!](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/)*,

> You have the option to retry with `--force` to bypass the conflict or
> `--legacy-peer-deps` command to ignore peer dependencies entirely
> (this behavior is similar to versions 4-6).

I agree this sentence is not really clear, but "ignore peer dependencies entirely" does not sound good. Let's use a real example:

Here is a peer dependency error I met when I `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mobile@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.0.0" from @testing-library/react-native@7.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react-native
npm ERR!     dev @testing-library/react-native@"7.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.13.1" from react-native@0.63.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@">=0.59" from @testing-library/react-native@7.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react-native
npm ERR!     dev @testing-library/react-native@"7.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/me/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2021-03-13T00_10_33_813Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/me/my-app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c sh ./bin/setup.sh

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2021-03-13T00_10_33_860Z-debug.log
```

Below is the **package-lock.json** difference between `--legacy-peer-deps` and `--force`.

1. If I run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`, it adds this in my **package-lock.json**:

```
"node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter": {
  "version": "5.7.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/-/react-native-adapter-5.7.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-L557/+sc8ZKJVgo1734HF1QNCxrt/fpqdmdNgySJT+kErux/AJNfPq3flsK0fyJduVmniTutYIMyW48cFoPKDA==",
  "dependencies": {
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-native": "*",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.7"
  }
},

...

"@unimodules/react-native-adapter": {
  "version": "5.7.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/-/react-native-adapter-5.7.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-L557/+sc8ZKJVgo1734HF1QNCxrt/fpqdmdNgySJT+kErux/AJNfPq3flsK0fyJduVmniTutYIMyW48cFoPKDA==",
  "requires": {
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.5.0"
  }
},
```

2. If I use `npm install --force`, instead, it adds

```
"node_modules/expo/node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter": {
  "version": "5.7.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/-/react-native-adapter-5.7.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-L557/+sc8ZKJVgo1734HF1QNCxrt/fpqdmdNgySJT+kErux/AJNfPq3flsK0fyJduVmniTutYIMyW48cFoPKDA==",
  "dependencies": {
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-native": "*",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.7"
  }
},
"node_modules/expo/node_modules/inline-style-prefixer": {
  "version": "5.1.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/inline-style-prefixer/-/inline-style-prefixer-5.1.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-PYUF+94gDfhy+LsQxM0g3d6Hge4l1pAqOSOiZuHWzMvQEGsbRQ/ck2WioLqrY2ZkHyPgVUXxn+hrkF7D6QUGbA==",
  "peer": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "css-in-js-utils": "^2.0.0"
  }
},
"node_modules/expo/node_modules/react-native-web": {
  "version": "0.13.18",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-web/-/react-native-web-0.13.18.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-WR/0ECAmwLQ2+2cL2Ur+0/swXFAtcSM0URoADJmG6D4MnY+wGc91JO8LoOTlgY0USBOY+qG/beRrjFa+RAuOiA==",
  "peer": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "array-find-index": "^1.0.2",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
    "deep-assign": "^3.0.0",
    "fbjs": "^1.0.0",
    "hyphenate-style-name": "^1.0.3",
    "inline-style-prefixer": "^5.1.0",
    "normalize-css-color": "^1.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.5.1",
    "react-dom": ">=16.5.1"
  }
},

...

  "dependencies": {
    "@unimodules/react-native-adapter": {
      "version": "5.7.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/-/react-native-adapter-5.7.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-L557/+sc8ZKJVgo1734HF1QNCxrt/fpqdmdNgySJT+kErux/AJNfPq3flsK0fyJduVmniTutYIMyW48cFoPKDA==",
      "requires": {
        "invariant": "^2.2.4",
        "lodash": "^4.5.0"
      }
    },
    "inline-style-prefixer": {
      "version": "5.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/inline-style-prefixer/-/inline-style-prefixer-5.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-PYUF+94gDfhy+LsQxM0g3d6Hge4l1pAqOSOiZuHWzMvQEGsbRQ/ck2WioLqrY2ZkHyPgVUXxn+hrkF7D6QUGbA==",
      "peer": true,
      "requires": {
        "css-in-js-utils": "^2.0.0"
      }
    },
    "react-native-web": {
      "version": "0.13.18",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native-web/-/react-native-web-0.13.18.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-WR/0ECAmwLQ2+2cL2Ur+0/swXFAtcSM0URoADJmG6D4MnY+wGc91JO8LoOTlgY0USBOY+qG/beRrjFa+RAuOiA==",
      "peer": true,
      "requires": {
        "array-find-index": "^1.0.2",
        "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
        "deep-assign": "^3.0.0",
        "fbjs": "^1.0.0",
        "hyphenate-style-name": "^1.0.3",
        "inline-style-prefixer": "^5.1.0",
        "normalize-css-color": "^1.0.2",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
        "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

As you see, `npm install --force` still pins many dependency versions which is stricter.

Comment: When I'm using `yarn` instead of `npm install` it does not seem to get any errors and it installs the packages without prompting any errors? Is there any problem using `yarn` instead of `npm`?

Comment: This is specific to `npm`

Comment: I don't quite understand, with `--legacy-peer-deps` it just doesn't install any of the peer dependencies?

Comment: @Plumpie Yes `--legacy-peer-deps` ignores peer dependencies entirely which may result in an incorrect/broken dependency resolution.

Comment: @Dillon so if I ignore peer dependencies entirely, the peer dependencies won't be installed automatically. That must mean that almost every package that has peerDependencies should not work correctly, because it relies on peer packages that are not installed. Am I right?

Answer (score 38):

For those wondering which is safer, the answer is `--force`

`--legacy-peer-deps` ignores peer dependencies entirely, which can screw up your dependency resolution.

`--force` on the other hand simply sets a different peer dependency version for conflicting dependencies

Using force isn't always ideal though because each dependency version takes up extra space. Using force with many dependencies will increase your total space requirement a decent amount.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a temporary workaround to get rid of npm peer dependency errors or ignore peer-dependencies, use --legacy-peer-deps but to set a different peer dependency tree than the conflicting one, use --force. Find more info [here](https://weekendprojects.dev/posts/how-to-use-npm-legacy-peer-deps-command/)