# What is the difference between npm install --force and npm install --legacy-peer-deps?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, node-modules

I am trying to install node_modules for a project using `npm install`. But it's failing.

**Error Log** :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-first-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@11.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~11.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"11.0.9" from @angular/compiler-cli@11.0.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~11.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"11.1.2" from @angular/localize@11.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/localize@"^11.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/amit/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/amit/.npm/_logs/2021-02-04T17_58_24_981Z-debug.log
```

Logs suggest to use either `npm install --force` or `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

I want to understand the basic difference between `npm install --force` and `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

Also, which one is more preferable to be used, just in case if performance of `--force` is better than `--legacy-peer-deeps` or vice-versa ?

Any suggestions/pointers are highly appreciable. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm: When to use \`--force\` and \`--legacy-peer-deps\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps)

Comment: Thanks @Joe! The question you suggested is similar to mine, But I am not really clear about the concept after going through the answer. It would be really helpful if one could help me understand the basic difference in Leyman's term.

Comment: I have updated the question for more clarity about what I am looking for, specifically.

Answer (score 2):

The differences between the two are below

`--legacy-peer-deps` : ignores all peerDependencies when installing, in the style of npm version 4 till version 6

`--strict-peer-deps:` fail and abort the install process for any conflicting peerDependencies when encountered. By default, npm will ony crash for peerDependencies conflicts caused by the direct dependencies of the root project.

`--forces :` will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.