# NPM ERR when installing particle.js in React

Tags: reactjs, npm, particle.js, react-particles-js

I am getting below error when installing *particle.js* in my React App:

```
code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: app-test@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project   
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-particles-js@3.4.1  
npm ERR! node_modules/react-particles-js
npm ERR!   react-particles-js@"*" from the root project      
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry      
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps    
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\gydee\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Comment: You need to downgrade your React version to version 16 because *react-particle-js* requires React V16 as its [peer-dependency](https://github.com/Wufe/react-particles-js/blob/84856a2ce47e41ace6dd6aaabf1189dfd830ca84/package.json#L41)

Comment: Or you can try [--legacy-peer-deps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66020820/2873538) option.

Comment: Or you can use `react-tsparticles` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tsparticles) (same core library, supports React 17)

Comment: thank you I have installed react version 17 + react version 16.8.4 and it works

Answer (score 3):

it is a problem coming from version 7 of npm use:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react-particles-js --force
```

Answer (score -1):

npm install react-particles-js --force or --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: This is just repeating the two existing answers.