# npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree when installing react-spring animation

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-spring

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.x" from @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm ERR!     @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@"^0.1.14" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^11.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   5 more (react-dom, react-scripts, the root project, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-reconciler@0.20.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-zdog/node_modules/react-reconciler
npm ERR!   react-reconciler@"^0.20.4" from react-zdog@1.0.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-zdog
npm ERR!     peer react-zdog@">=1.0" from @react-spring/zdog@9.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-spring/zdog
npm ERR!       @react-spring/zdog@"^9.0.0" from react-spring@9.0.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-spring
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\FUJITSU\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/66020820/2873538

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67258731/13983502 Apparently this solution works. Try it out.