# React spring Errors while installing

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, react-spring

Hi I have this problem where if I want to install react-spring into my react project It just pops up bunch of dependencies errors and warnings and I don't know what to do with it. I tried to check documentation of react-spring but I couldn't find anything. I checked few pages here on stackoverflow and I still did not find anything useful. Can somebody help?

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.8" from @react-spring/konva@9.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/@react-spring/konva
npm WARN     @react-spring/konva@"^9.0.0" from react-spring@9.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-spring
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"16.8.x" from react-konva@16.8.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/react-konva
npm WARN   peer react-konva@">=16.8" from @react-spring/konva@9.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/@react-spring/konva
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@">=16.8" from @react-spring/konva@9.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/@react-spring/konva
npm WARN     @react-spring/konva@"^9.0.0" from react-spring@9.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-spring
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-dom@16.8.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"16.8.x" from react-konva@16.8.6
npm WARN   node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/react-konva
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: konva@7.2.5
npm WARN node_modules/konva
npm WARN   peer konva@">=2.6" from @react-spring/konva@9.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/@react-spring/konva
npm WARN     @react-spring/konva@"^9.0.0" from react-spring@9.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-spring
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer konva@"^3.2.3" from react-konva@16.8.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/react-konva
npm WARN   peer react-konva@">=16.8" from @react-spring/konva@9.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-spring/node_modules/@react-spring/konva
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-spring@9.0.0
npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peerOptional react-dom@">=17.0" from @react-three/fiber@6.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-three/fiber
npm WARN     peer @react-three/fiber@">=6.0" from @react-spring/three@9.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/@react-spring/three
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional react-dom@">=17.0" from @react-three/fiber@6.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/@react-three/fiber
npm WARN   peer @react-three/fiber@">=6.0" from @react-spring/three@9.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@react-spring/three
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^11.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"17.0.1" from react-dom@17.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!       @testing-library/react@"^11.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@">=16.0.0" from react-visibility-sensor@5.1.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-visibility-sensor
npm ERR!       react-visibility-sensor@"^5.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   4 more (react-scripts, react-visibility-sensor, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from react-reconciler@0.26.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-three/fiber/node_modules/react-reconciler
npm ERR!   react-reconciler@"^0.26.2" from @react-three/fiber@6.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-three/fiber
npm ERR!     peer @react-three/fiber@">=6.0" from @react-spring/three@9.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-spring/three
npm ERR!       @react-spring/three@"^9.0.0" from react-spring@9.0.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-spring
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: did u try global install? npm install -g react-spring or try npm install react-spring --save

Comment: what version of react and react-dom are you using?

Comment: @arminyahya "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",

Comment: @ksa I tried both on global it wont compile on --save it wont install and have same problem

Comment: looks like react spring dependencies needs react and react-dom 17.0.2 can u try upate this packages to this version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is with npm7 requiring peer deps to be installed. This is a feature of npm7, not a bug. `react-spring` is the global package for the library and therefore contains all our targets. Unless you really are doing an app that requires `zDog`, `konva` etc. I would install the specific target you're after.

i.e `npm install @react-spring/web` the /* can be replaced with any target we support, for more information please see the [docs](https://www.react-spring.dev/docs/concepts/targets#what-is-a-target)

Comment: Coming from the GitHub issue I've opened. Thank you for adding your answer here @Josh! In my case, I needed @react-spring/web only for Next.js.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out.
P.S. I guess it will make my Stack Overflow glory down. But it was worth the run. :)

Answer (score 10):

Had the same problem, [this](https://github.com/pmowrer/rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external/issues/28) suggestion fixed the installation error.
Still didn't try to work with it though.
Basically, we should add

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react-spring": "^8.x"
}
```

to the package.json file

Comment: Worked with it now, may confirm that this solution works. :)

Comment: For me, it automaitclaly installs up to React-Spring v7. Can we upgrade it to V9?

Comment: I don 't think is the correct answer. It's probably to do with npm7 requiring all the peer deps to be in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Got the similar kind of problem when added "@twilio/video-room-monitor": "^1.0.1" dependency and resolved by adding  "react-spring" in dependencies, reference [link](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react/issues/612)

```
 "dependencies": {
 "react-spring": "^9.6.1"
```

}

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem using React 17.0.2 but success with run npm install -g react-spring and then go without errors but still a lot of warnings