# How to use npm install without the --legacy-peer-deps flag to resolve a conflicting peer dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, azure-pipelines, handsontable

I am having trouble with a peer dependcy called zone.js. Version ^0.8.19 is required for @handsontable/angular but version ~0.10.2 is required for @angular/core and others. I get this error message when I try npm install.

```
While resolving: @angular/core@9.0.7
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.8.29
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"^0.8.19" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer zone.js@"^0.8.19" from @handsontable/angular@2.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@handsontable/angular
npm ERR!     @handsontable/angular@"2.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer zone.js@"~0.10.2" from @angular/core@9.0.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~9.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"9.0.7" from @angular/animations@9.0.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"~9.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (@angular/material, @angular/platform-browser)
npm ERR!   10 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/common, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: zone.js@0.10.3
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   peer zone.js@"~0.10.2" from @angular/core@9.0.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!     @angular/core@"~9.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/core@"9.0.7" from @angular/animations@9.0.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!       @angular/animations@"~9.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@angular/material, @angular/platform-browser)
npm ERR!     10 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/common, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Attempt #1 Update package.json
After deleting package-lock.json and node_modules I tried npm install with the updated version shown below. My understanding is that the ^0.8.19 should include 0.8.19 to <1.0.0. Wouldn't 0.10.2 fall in this range?

```
 "dependencies": {
    ...
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
```

Attempt #2 --legacy-peer-deps
I want to avoid using this flag because this ultimately runs in a pipeline without the flag. Would updating the command to npm install --legacy-peer-deps be risky or dangerous? I have little experience with pipelines and all the senior devs who set this up quit :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm: When to use \`--force\` and \`--legacy-peer-deps\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to retry with `--force` to bypass the conflict or `--legacy-peer-deps` command to ignore peer dependencies entirely.

By default, In the new version of npm (v7),  `npm install` will fail when it encounters conflicting peerDependencies. It was not like that before.

The differences between the two are below -

`--legacy-peer-deps`: ignore all peerDependencies when installing, in the style of npm version 4 through version 6.

`--strict-peer-deps`: fail and abort the install process for any conflicting peerDependencies when encountered. By default, npm will only crash for peerDependencies conflicts caused by the direct dependencies of the root project.

`--force`: will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.

Answer (score -1):

this cmd finally worked for me ... atleast tried it

```
npm install <package> --legacy-peer-deps
```