# errors while install material-ui

Tags: reactjs, terminal, material-ui

I am trying to install material ui but I am facing multiple errors. I am making a website that has a map on it to show different outlets but when I try to install material ui and google maps api, I am facing many errors.

Command I am trying to run -

```
$ npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/lab @react-google- 
maps/api axios google-map-react
```

Error - [Errors in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W63kS.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error comes on npm V8.x.x . To resolve
run the command below:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

You can find more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps)