# what is `npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve` when I run `npm install`?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I use node.js 18.12.0 and npm 8.19.2 and when I run `npm install` this error is shown:
[image: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve]

I can run it with `--force` but dependency tree problem will happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm: When to use \`--force\` and \`--legacy-peer-deps\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps)

Comment: see github issue [4998](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4998) and [5113](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5113)

Answer (score -3):

try installing dependendies with yarn

```
npm install -g yarn
```

then just do

```
yarn install
```