# Can't install material-ui in my react project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrHIR.png)When I paste `npm install @material-ui/core`  in my root directory, the following is displayed:

I was trying to improve the UI of my app using material-UI. It's my first time using material-UI.

Comment: You didn't include the output

Comment: What output kindly

Comment: use this: [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps). I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply clone MUI official example
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/create-react-app
or you can check this repo configurations and installed libraries