# Error when trying to install react-router-dom dependency npm on Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, npm-start, yarn-lock.json

I am getting an error trying to install the npm onto my create-react - app application. I have tried deleting and reinstalling my node_modules folder as well as installing it with admin permissions and I am still receiving the same error

**Here is the output from the console
**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @nt/xps-base-app@1.5.5
npm ERR! Found: react-router-dom@5.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-router-dom
npm ERR!   react-router-dom@"^5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-router-dom@"\>=5.1.0" from @okta/okta-react@4.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@okta/okta-react
npm ERR!     @okta/okta-react@"^4.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-router-dom@"5.1.2" from @nt/xps-base-app@1.5.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@nt/xps-base-app
npm ERR!   @nt/xps-base-app@"^1.5.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-router-dom@5.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-router-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-router-dom@"5.1.2" from @nt/xps-base-app@1.5.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nt/xps-base-app
npm ERR!     @nt/xps-base-app@"^1.5.4" from the root project
```

**list of dependencies from package.json
**

```
"dependencies": {
        "@nt/eslint-config-xps-base": "^1.6.4",
        "@nt/xps-base-app": "^1.5.4",
        "@okta/okta-auth-js": "4.6.1",
        "@okta/okta-react": "^4.1.0",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
        "@types/text-encoding": "^0.0.35",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "eslint": "5.15.1",
        "jest-junit": "6.4.0",
        "moment": "2.24.0",
        "prop-types": "15.7.2",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-axe": "3.3.0",
        "react-cookie": "^4.0.3",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-media": "2.0.0-rc.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-with-direction": "1.3.1",
        "retry-axios": "^2.4.0",
        "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.3",
        "uuid": "^3.4.0",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
        "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
        "xps-react": "1.7.0",
        "xps-style": "1.7.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@nt/xps-dev-utils": "^1.6.2",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
        "text-encoding": "^0.7.0"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why we have this error a lot but a while ago someone else points out this error to me. That time we use a couple of commands. first this: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps @youpackagename` then we had to use this: `npm install --force @yourpackagename` you may not need the second command check your project before you use the second. You can go to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps) for more information.