# npm install failing in git action but working locally

Tags: node.js, npm, github-actions

Git action `npm`install` failing while it works on my machine. This my action

```
name: Check for lint/build errors

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - '**'

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        submodules: recursive
        token: ${{ secrets.SEMANTIC_RELEASE_PAT }}

    - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 16
        registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

    - name: Set NPM_TOKEN
      run: echo "NPM_TOKEN=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: npm install, lint
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run lint
```

In my machine, I am using `node` version `v16.3.0`

Ps: On my local machine, I have removed `package-lock.json` and it still works fine.
Here is the exact error

```
npm ERR! While resolving: @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.15.9
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.68.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.68.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@">=0.64.0-rc.0 || 0.0.0-*" from @react-native-community/cli@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm ERR!     dev @react-native-community/cli@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   11 more (react-native-actions-sheet, react-native-check-box, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native@"^0.0.0-0 || ^0.60.6 || ^0.61.5 || ^0.62.2 || ^0.63.2 || ^0.64.0 || ^0.65.0 || ^0.66.0 || 1000.0.0" from @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.15.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage
npm ERR!   @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@"^1.15.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native@0.66.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"^0.0.0-0 || ^0.60.6 || ^0.61.5 || ^0.62.2 || ^0.63.2 || ^0.64.0 || ^0.65.0 || ^0.66.0 || 1000.0.0" from @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.15.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage
npm ERR!     @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@"^1.15.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/runner/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-12-30T10_36_18_687Z-debug-0.log
```

Any idea why this could be happening and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `package-lock.json` to your git repository.

Second option that is not recommended and can lead to hard to reproduce behaviours is

```
npm i --force
```

You can check difference between force and legacy-peer-deps here:

[npm: When to use `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps)

To reporoduce this problem locally you have to remove not only `package-lock.json` but also `node_modules`.