# Is npm install "--force" mandatory on latest version of node

Tags: node.js, npm

**Context / Background :**

I was using node version 16.10.0 using nvm . There was conflict between 2 packages so I resolved it with --force . Afterwards if just npm install was performed on same/other machine , it was working fine without throwing any conflict error.

**Issue :**

In the latest version of node . I am required to use npm install --force every time else it throws conflict error.

Right now I am trying to upgrade to latest node version (Tried with 18.12.1 / 18.13.0 / 19.6.0) . I performed above steps again  BUT here just npm install is not working , --force is required every time .

I tried to find the relevant doc to confirm "--force is must on every npm install" OR "conflicts resolution are not getting saved in package-lock.json" .

Comment: Do you want to mention which specific packages are in conflict?  It would presumably allow others to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sorry , those are internal packages to organization so could not share . 

Also I need only the confirmation with relevant doc  saying --force is saving/not-saving  the conflict resolution in package-lock.json in latest node OR --force is mandatory to be performed on every npm install
===================================
Meanwhile I will try to reproduce the issue with opensource package and put the details here.. Thanks you

Comment: Perhaps you should look at [npm: When to use `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66020820/1563833)