# Error while deploying REACT App on Vercel "npm ERR! While resolving: react-lottie@1.2.3"

Tags: reactjs, npm, netlify, vercel, lottie

I get an error while deploying my REACT App on Vercel, Netlify etc. It seems it is related to lottiefiles. Does it mean I cannot use lottiefiles in my React App?

Refer to the screenshot for details.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ml9q.jpg

I tried updating my NPM, and reinstalling react-lottie. But it didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least on Netlify, you can solve this by adding a environment variable with the name `NPM_FLAGS` and the value as either `--legacy-peer-deps` or `--force` (whichever works for your setup).

As for why, you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66035709/9579545