# Mathematical equation in website using mathjax-angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mathjax

I am trying to convert latex format of mathematical equation to website in angular 13 application. I found mathjax-angular for this and trying to install using

```
npm install mathjax-angular
```

But I got some peer dependency errors as below.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: metric-tutorial@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.3.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0" from mathjax-angular@2.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/mathjax-angular
npm ERR!   mathjax-angular@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

What do you suggest for this problem? Do you have any suggestion to convert latex format to website for mathematical notation?

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps)

This is an issue with npm versions. In older versions, legacy peer dependencies confilcts were ignored, that changed in newer versions.

Run:

```
npm install mathjax-angular --legacy-peer-deps
```