# Hi, I was committing my changes in Vscode. I was not able to do it

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

The error says

> ✖ npm run lint:eslint:fix found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.
> Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
> pre-commit: We've failed to pass the specified git pre-commit hooks as the `lint:staged`
> pre-commit: hook returned an exit code (1). If you're feeling adventurous you can
> pre-commit: skip the git pre-commit hooks by adding the following flags to your commit:
> pre-commit:
> pre-commit:   git commit -n (or --no-verify)
> pre-commit:
> pre-commit: This is ill-advised since the commit is broken.

This is what I see tried to run npm update but I see this now

> npm WARN update-browserslist-db@1.0.11 requires a peer of browserslist@>= 4.21.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

I tried to fix it but still seeing these errors, can someone help me fixing this issue.

Comment: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` use this command to install the legacy packages

Comment: Your project has set up [Git Hooks](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks) such that it runs `npm run lint:eslint:fix` before committing. Since ESLint has detected errors in your code, it prevents you from committing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm: When to use \`--force\` and \`--legacy-peer-deps\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps)

Comment: how can we tell you how to fix the lint errors without seeing the full errors, or the code the error messages are referring to? please provide a [mre]