# Installation of eslint in a vanilla create-react-app --template typescript folder fails

Tags: reactjs, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am trying to install eslint into a vanilla create-react-app folder that has been created from the TypeScript template.

I ran the following:

```shell
% npx create-react-app REDACTED --template typescript

Creating a new React app in REDACTED.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template-typescript...


added 1427 packages in 13s

231 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Installing template dependencies using npm...

added 52 packages, and changed 2 packages in 3s

240 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

We detected TypeScript in your project (src/App.test.tsx) and created a tsconfig.json file for you.

Your tsconfig.json has been populated with default values.

Removing template package using npm...


removed 1 package, and audited 1479 packages in 2s

240 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Success! Created trip-quoter at REDACTED
```

Great, I now have a vanilla CRA app from the TypeScript template.

Now I try to install eslint:

```shell
% npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin eslint
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: REDACTED@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.62.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.5.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm ERR!     eslint-config-react-app@"^7.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!       react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from eslint-plugin-jest@25.7.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-plugin-jest
npm ERR!     eslint-plugin-jest@"^25.3.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm ERR!       eslint-config-react-app@"^7.0.1" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         react-scripts@"5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @typescript-eslint/parser@6.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
npm ERR!   peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^6.0.0 || ^6.0.0-alpha" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@6.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Looks like some kind of dependency madness. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is, sadly, one of several open bugs around peer dependency mismatches in `create-typescript-app`: [#13259](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13259), [#13080](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13080), [#13071](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/13071). `create-react-app` is not actively maintained the way it used to be ([#13289](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13289), [#13393](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13393)) so it's not likely those will be resolved soon.

To get around this issue without changing much code, you can follow the steps suggested in the message of using either `npm install --force` or `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. See [npm: When to use `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps) for more details on that.

Alternately, you could `npm run eject` to put all the dependencies, scripts, settings, etc. that were previously hidden by `create-react-app`'s `react-scripts` directly into your `package.json`. This would let you manually upgrade packages to newer versions to satisfy any version mismatches. Beware, though - oftentimes this can end up being a lot of work!

---

Thinking more meta: given that `create-react-app` isn't actively maintained anymore, you might consider switching to another meta-React-framework. https://react.dev's homepage mentions: *To build an entire app with React, we recommend a full-stack React framework like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org) or [Remix](https://remix.run)*. [Astro](https://astro.build) is a popular option too.

If you really want to get as close an equivalent to `create-react-app` as possible (i.e. don't want a full-stack app or static site), [Vite](https://vitejs.dev) is a good popular alternative these days.

Comment: If you are used to CRA's style of React app, I would recommend going with Vite.  The other frameworks are good, but involve having a lot more (re-/un-)learning to do, whereas you can typically get started with Vite right away if you have used CRA in the past.