# Incompatibility problem with my .tflite model into react-native expo app

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tflite

Im using react-native with expo and npm, i have a problem using my model.tflite.

I tried many times with the installation of many react-native libraries for example react-native-fast-tflite or tensorflow/tfjs but all of these provided me problems during installation because of expo-camera version incompatibility. i tried to change the version of the expo camera but nothing seems work. i tried also the forced installation but it doesn't work too. Do you think there are a solution?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: real2@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: expo-camera@13.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/expo-camera
npm ERR!   expo-camera@"^13.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer expo-camera@"^7.0.0" from @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@0.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native
npm ERR!   @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm: When to use \`--force\` and \`--legacy-peer-deps\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps)

Answer (score 0):

I tried --legacy-peer-deps and now its working fine with me.