# i am having error trying to use npm install to download a packages for my cloned projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, clone

I am having errors when i clone a file from Github and try to run `npm install`

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: light-blue-react-template@1.2.5
npm ERR! Found: eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.8.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-flowtype
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-flowtype@"3.8.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint-plugin-flowtype@"2.x" from eslint-config-react-app@4.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
npm ERR!   dev eslint-config-react-app@"4.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\JUWONCALEB.DESKTOP-CMA289U\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JUWONCALEB.DESKTOP-CMA289U\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-12T12_22_41_858Z-debug.log
```

Comment: This thread might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages
Please check.

Answer (score -1):

I get this issue sometimes when using node v15.10.0.
Try using the LTS version. (v14.16.10)

https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.16.0/node-v14.16.0.pkg