# How can resolve this situation Error ERESOLVE could not resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

After running `npm install`, first I got an error with `jasmine-core`.

After solving that, I'm getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@11.0.9
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"^11.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"11.0.9" from @angular/compiler-cli@11.0.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~11.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1100.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^11.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"11.2.14" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@11.2.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm ERR!     @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^11.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/salami/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/salami/.npm/_logs/2021-09-25T09_49_52_657Z-debug.log
```

What is that I'm doing wrong or should fix?

I will add my package.json file if it's needed.

**Updated:**

after running with --force I'm getting this error now :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^11.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@"^12.0.0" from @angular/flex-layout@12.0.0-beta.35
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
npm ERR!     @angular/flex-layout@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/salami/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/salami/.npm/_logs/2021-09-25T12_07_03_361Z-debug.log
```

THis is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.7",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.7",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.14",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.2",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 17):

If dependency conflict occurred, try running with `--force` argument as below:

```bash
npm install --legacy-peer-deps --force
```

Comment: check it now @potter-potter

Comment: thanks, `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` resolved my issue