# Could not resolve dependency: google-maps-react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, installation, next.js

It is my first time to clone react project from github

i did:

```
$ git clone <link>
```

after that:

```
npm install
```

but i faced an error with google-maps-react

```
$ npm install --save google-maps-react
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @iso/here@4.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from google-maps-react@2.0.6
npm ERR! node_modules/google-maps-react
npm ERR!   google-maps-react@"^2.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

i tried:

```
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm install -g npm
```

,:

```
$npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

,:

```
npm install  --force
```

,:

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

,:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

and more ..

node js version:

```
16.13.2
```

react version:

```
17.0.2
```

npm version:

```
8.4.1
```

nothing seem to work

am i missing something?

Comment: have you tried delete next and node_modules folder and run yarn?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix the upstream dependency conflict installing NPM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936044/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-installing-npm-packages)

Answer (score 0):

[The project has a peer dependency](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/master/package.json#L81) on React 15 or 16 and you are using 17.0.2 - The npm error states the reason

Downgrade your react version if you want to use this library as is or change the package.json for the lib, test and confirm to the author that they are good on 17.0.2 raising a PR

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"
  },
```

Here's npm telling you reason in the log

`npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The app is using "yarn"
I'm able now to run the app after installing "yarn add node-sass"

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem. To solve this you can "force" flag in npm install.
i.e. In vercel in project setting just add `npm install --force` in "Instal Command" section.

Works fine for me:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by downgrading my node version from 18 to 16.14.0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).